# Pass to javascript a dictionary of a dictionary (.NET)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, web-services, soap, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to solve the problem of passing a 2-dimensional table into JavaScript AJAX application through SOAP web services. I'm trying to pass data into JavaScript web page through ASP.NET web service declared with following attributes:

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

I need a complex type to be passed into the JavaScript:

```
[Serializable]
public class PayRateSummary
{
    public string[] EmployeeId;
    public Dictionary<string, string> EmployeeName;
    public string[] PaycodeId;
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double?>> EmployeePaycodeRate;
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public DataElements.PayRateSummary EnumPayRates(Guid companyId)
{
}
```

And web service declared in a pretty standard way:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1">
        <Services><asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService.asmx" /></Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

...
        function RefreshPayRates() {
            WebService.EnumPayRates(CompanyCurrent, OnPayRatesLoaded, OnFailure);
        }

For some reason, Dictionary[string,string] is getting passed allright, but not the Dictionary[string,Dictionary[string,string]]:

--> http://vvcap.net/db/8rveoL-FMP6EUikCaqiz.htp

I remember beating my head against the wall in the past to understand, what could be done to pass such objects and never found any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on [sktrdie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411896/pass-to-javascript-a-dictionary-of-a-dictionary-net#411924)'s answer, You could use ASP.NET AJAX JSON Web Services to pass and return the data as JSON objects. Here are some examples-

- [Using ASP.NET AJAX 3.5 JSON Web
  Services](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=264)
- [Using JSON Syntax with
      ASP.NET AJAX](http://quickstarts.asp.net/previews/ajax/jsonsyntax.aspx)
- [Understanding
      ASP.NET AJAX Web Service Proxies](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2006/12/28/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-service-proxies.aspx)

There is a lot of good information on JSON in this question - [What is JSON and why would I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

**EDIT -**

At the moment, you say that you are using [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Object_Access_Protocol), which is an XML-based transport protocol. There is a very succinct article here - [Extending an existing ASP.NET Web Service to support JSON](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/XML_and_JSON_on_same_We_S.aspx) -  that explains how to extend an existing web service,

In addition, if you do not have access to .NET 3.5 JSON serializer/deserializer, have a look at [James Newton King's JSON.NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

**EDIT 2 -**

Looking at your screenshot again and the fact that you have the [ScriptService] attribute, you appear to be returning a JSON string (which I understand is the default). Therefore, I'm thinking is the ASP.NET AJAX JSON serializer failing to serialize the nullable double in this line

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double?>> EmployeePaycodeRate;
```

to the correct JSON data type in each instance? You could see whether this is the case by changing the web service to return a double, and then try it with data that have values.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx)-

> Nullable types are also supported and map to JSON in the same way as non-nullable types.

Nonetheless, I think it's worth looking at in a similar manner to as I have suggested, as this is where your problem is occurring

Hope this helps

**EDIT 3 -**

It seems strange why a Dictionary with a Dictionary value would not be possible to represent in a JSON string. Consider that a Dictionary looks like this in JSON

```
[{"Key":"a1","Value":"a1"},
{"Key":"a2","Value":"a2"}]
```

A Dictionary with a Dictionary value would therefore look like so (I believe)

```
[{"Key":"a1","Value": {"Key":"b1","Value":"b1"} },
{"Key":"a2","Value": {"Key":"b2","Value":"b2"} }]
```

which is valid JSON according to [JSONLint - the JSON validator](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

Comment: According to your description, your're using SOAP, which is an XML-based transfer protocol. I'll update my answer with more info

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a dictionary of dictionary which is the problem. I tried to refactor structure to: 

    public double?[][] EmployeePaycodeRate;

and that worked. Not that it's unacceptable, but I would rather prefer dictionary of dictionary, but if this won't work, oh well

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using this: http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/

I'm not familiar with ASP, but in PHP i use something similar to convert PHP native Objects into JSON objects.