# What is JSON used for in web applications?

Tags: json, web-applications

I am relatively new to web development and web applications. I have heard about JSON but am not sure exactly what its uses are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is JSON and why would I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSON is a format for encoding information returned by the server. When you call a script with AJAX/XHR (e.g. with JavaScript) the returned information can come via XML, JSON, or another format. JSON is simply a way to return that data in an object structure native to JavaScript - in a way that generally doesn't require a lot of parsing, like XML does.

Comment: +1 JSON is a *subset* of JavaScript object literal notation is well suited to modeling objects composed of dictionaries, lists and primitive values -- especially JavaScript objects. A JSON parser (turns JSON into JavaScript objects, for instance) is therefor a direct transformation. XML, on the other hand, generally isn't able/used to provide this simple mapping and generally requires a conversion/extraction from the XML document or fragment. This *simplicity* is one of JSON's biggest strengths.

Answer (score 4):

It is a kind of language for encoding information. For example, if you want to send information about person from one place to another, then it JSON it may look like this:

```
{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "age": 25,
     "address":
     {
         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
         "city": "New York",
         "state": "NY",
         "postalCode": "10021"
     },
     "phoneNumber":
     [
         {
           "type": "home",
           "number": "212 555-1234"
         },
         {
           "type": "fax",
           "number": "646 555-4567"
         }
     ]
 }
```

Taken from wiki. :) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON for more details.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation.

It is often used in places where applications deal with object data structures (often seen in languages such as Java, C#, etc.), and associative arrays (key-value pairs seen in many languages such as Python, PHP, etc.)

To answer your question, it's a simple and efficient way to encode objects into strings, transfer them, and recreate the objects on the other end.

[JSON on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

[JSON Homepage](http://www.json.org/)

[Example of JSON encoding in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)