# function.call() or click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, events

I am currently working on a menu in jQuery, which has keyboard shortcuts for the menu items, as well as access keys.

I pass data to build the menu using an object literal, which storesd the function that is to be bound to the menu item, something like this:

```
var my_menu = [
    { 
        label     : 'File',
        accessKey : 'F',
        func      : function() { alert('File shown'); } 
    }
];
```

I am binding the `func` function to the menu item (an `<li>` element) using jQuery's `click()` function, something like:

```
this_li.click(function() { this_click_func.call() });
```

I then add keyboard support by listening for `keydown()` on the `document`. If the combination of keys match the `accessKey`, I simply use the `click()` method in jQuery to fire the function, even though in reality, they haven't clicked the item.

This works fine, but I wanted opinion on this method. Would it be better practice to run the function when the combination of keys match as well, or is it sufficient to simply replicate a click using `click()`?

Any comments gratefully received.

Comment: "I made this, any thoughts?" isn't *answerable*.

Comment: That's not JSON. That's a JavaScript object literal. Regardless, this is perhaps a better question for http://s.tk/review.

Comment: please post under http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a nitpick, but `my_menu` is not JSON: JSON doesn't have functions. It's a javascript object. Also a nitpick, unless you need to change the function signature, you can register the handler with simply `this_li.click(this_click_func);`--the closure is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not trigger the `click()` handler, as *other* components/ plugins may also have subscribed to the `click()` event.

In your `keydown()` handler you should again call `this_click_func.call()`.

Furthermore, what you've got is [Object Literal Notation, **not** JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json/8294127#8294127).