# How do I add items to a nested Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array such as this in Javascript:

```
var cars = { vendor: [ { type: [ 'camry', 'etc' ] } ] }
```

In Javascript what command can I use to add an item to type... For example if I wanted to have a text box that a user can place text into and then hit a button that will add the item into the array. The item that would be added would need to be placed in with the same items as "camry" and "etc". Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try something like

```
cars.vendor[0].type.push("foo");
```

Where "foo" is your data to add.

Answer (score 7):

You can add items to the array using the [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to add to the end, or [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to add to the front.

```
var newValue = 1234;

cars.vendor[0].type.push(newValue);
```

The event handler could then be bound using something similar to this;

```
$("yourSelector").on("click", function(){
    var value = $("input").val();

    cars.vendor[0].type.push(value);
});
```

*Please* bear in mind that what you have is not JSON at all. It's a nested structure of JavaScript Objects and Arrays, declared using literal syntax. See [Javascript object Vs JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Test example for this problem as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var cars = {
        "vendor": [
            {
                "type": [
                    "camry",
                    "maruti",
                    "bmw"
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
    $("#add").click(function(){
        var types=cars["vendor"][0]["type"];
        types.push($("#json").val());
        $("#types").html(types.toString());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="json" name="json"/>
<input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="ADD"/>
<div id="types" style="margin:10px;border:1px dotted green;width:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awakening the dinosaur here but what if there wasn't a "type" defined yet, meaning the user first landed on the page and wanted to dynamically build the vendor object?

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like given below

```
var cars = { vendor: [ { type: [ 'camry', 'etc' ] } ] } ;
cars.vendor[0].type[2]="abc";
```