# Is there any way to manipulate this data into the desired format please?

Tags: javascript, json

**I would like to go from this:**

```
[ { compID: 1, problem: 1, usersID: 1, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 1, usersID: 5, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 2, usersID: 1, completed: 0 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 2, usersID: 5, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 3, usersID: 1, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 3, usersID: 5, completed: 0 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 4, usersID: 1, completed: 0 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 4, usersID: 5, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 5, usersID: 1, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 5, usersID: 5, completed: 0 } ]
```

**To this:**

```
[ { compID: 1, problem: [1,2,3,4,5], usersID: 1, completed: [1,0,1,0,1] },

  { compID: 1, problem: [1,2,3,4,5], usersID: 5, completed: [1,1,0,1,0] } ]
```

I will need to do this manipulation for each usersID. 
Thank you

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: maybe this stackoverflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016546/transform-json-object-to-another-format-it) may give you an idea of how to go about achieving what you intend to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to manipulate your array to get the result. You can try like below,

```
 var data = [ { compID: 1, problem: 1, usersID: 1, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 1, usersID: 5, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 2, usersID: 1, completed: 0 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 2, usersID: 5, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 3, usersID: 1, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 3, usersID: 5, completed: 0 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 4, usersID: 1, completed: 0 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 4, usersID: 5, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 5, usersID: 1, completed: 1 },
  { compID: 1, problem: 5, usersID: 5, completed: 0 } ]

var res ={};

data.map(d => {
  if(res[d.usersID]) {
    res[d.usersID].problem.push(d.problem);
    res[d.usersID].completed.push(d.completed);
  } else {
    res[d.usersID] = {compID: d.compID, problem: [d.problem], usersID: d.usersID, completed: [d.completed]  }
  }
})

console.log(Object.values(res))
```