# Table json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to make json object of html table in javascript.Currently I am able to read the each cells value in javascript, the only problem is that I am not able to retrieve as per my need so think of any suggestion here. Currently getting value like:

```
var x = document.getElementById("tableId");

for (var i = 0; i < x.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < x.rows[i].cells.length; j++){
            tableJsonDTO[name] = x.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

This is how i am able to read the each cell value.The table format is as follow:

```
header:      company_1      company_2      company_3

Question1    answer_1       answer_1       answer_1

Question2     answer_2       answer_2       answer_2
```

and so on.How can i read the value so that i can get object like:

```
var obj = [{spname:"company_1",qalist:[{question:"",answer:""},{question:"",answer:""}]},{spname:"company_2",qalist:[{question:"",answer:""},{question:"",answer:""}]},{spname:"company_3",qalist:[{question:"",answer:""},{question:"",answer:""}]}]
```

Please give some suggestion.

Comment: Hope the below site helps you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507222/create-json-object-dynamically-via-javascript-without-concate-strings

Comment: sorry there the situation is that the rows are different.

Comment: you have to transpose the table first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730699/convert-td-columns-into-tr-rows   [link to JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/b76aks69/)

Comment: as per design concert we cant transpose table but for json object it is ok, so on jsfiddle how to get json object as shown in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to change the way you put values to `tableJsonDTO`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hru04myk/).

```
document.getElementById('toJSON').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var table = document.getElementById('mytable'),
        names = [].slice.call(table.rows[0].cells), 
        values = [].slice.call(table.rows, 1),
        out = {};


    values.forEach(function(row) { //iterate over values
        var cells = row.cells,
            caption = cells[0].innerHTML; //get property name

        [].forEach.call(cells, function(cell, idx) { //iterate over answers
            var value = {}, 
                arr;
            if(!idx) return; //ignore first column

            value[caption] = cell.innerHTML; //prepare value

            //get or init array of values for each name
            arr = out[names[idx].innerHTML] || (out[names[idx].innerHTML] = []);

            arr.push(value); 
        });
    });

    console.log(out);
});
```

Comment: sorry but I am trying to iterate object it is giving undefined error.

Comment: @user3406754 hmm which line?

Comment: sorry but instead of var obj = {company_1: [{Question1: answer_1},{Question2: answer_2}],company_2[{Question1: answer_1},{Question_2:answer_2}]};  can I get the var obj = {[name:company_1,[{Question1: answer_1},{Question2: answer_2}]],[name:company_2,[{Question1: answer_1},{Question2: answer_2}]]}

Comment: please suggest something.

Comment: @user3406754 you can't have structure like this `var obj = {[name:company_1,[{Question1: answer_1},{Question2: answer_2}]],[name:company_2,[{Question1: answer_1},{Question2: answer_2}]]}` syntax is invalid.

Comment: Still invalid syntax.

Comment: current output is:
{company_1: Array[2], company_2: Array[2], company_3: Array[2]}
  and 
required is:
{[spname: company_1,qalist:Array[2]],[spname: company_2,qalist:Array[2]],[spname: company_3,qalist:Array[2]]}

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I got it on my own soon I will update it.