# How to create multi-dimentional array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create an array like this:

```
events: [
    id   :'1',
    title: 'All Day Event'
},{
    id   : '2',
    title: 'some name'
},{
    id: 999,
    title: 'some title',
}]
```

I am executing this code inside a loop:

```
$events['title'] = 'hello';
$events['id'] = '1';
```

It's returning:

```
[ title: "hello", id: "1" ]
[ title: "hello", id: "1" ]
```

How can I change the code to meet my requirement?

Comment: Where's the code? and that's not _array_, it's an **object**

Comment: Just FYI that's not a multi-dimensional array - it's an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    var id1 = '1';
    var title1 = 'All Day Event';
    var events = [];
    events.push({
            id   :id1,
            title: title1
          });
```

for a loop:

```
titles = ['All Day Event1','All Day Event2'];
ids = ['1','2'];//note both array need to have the same length

$.each(titles,function(i,v){
 events.push({
                id   :ids[i],
                title: titles[i]//or v
              });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

See some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507222/create-json-object-dynamically-via-javascript-without-concate-strings) and read some more about [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp)

You need to iterate the JSON while adding dimensions and values in it