# Populating JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

We have an empty object:

var obj = {};

I would like to make a for loop which with each iteration adds a new obj = {value: i, next: i+1}

Comment: what you mean adds a new obj?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function () {})`

Comment: what's the result you want to get? an array of objects like `[{value: 1, next: 2}, {value: 2, next: 3}]`?

Comment: for loop over what? To add a new obj to what?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an array of objects and for every iteration push this values on it:

```
var obj=[];
for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
    obj.push({value: i, next: i+1});
}
```

This is [**a DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbxqx1jc/3/).

For each iteration give the `obj.value` and the `obj.next`, take a look at **[JavaScript Object Properties](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp)** for futher information.

Comment: I doesn't work because it keeps overwrite the obj.value and obj.next with a new value.

Comment: Yes of course it doesn't, sorry but you have to use an array of objects instead, because an Object can't contain different values for the same property. Take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: first, your answer is incorrect - you forgot to `obj.push(newobj)` to array. Second, no need to create variable: `array.push({value: i, next: i+1});`

Comment: @chsdk this is not JSON, this is js object, so it's not necessary to use quotes in key names.

Comment: @chsdk i don't see the difference between results in both cases. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json)

Comment: @KirillPisarev yes you are right, I just had a little confusion.

Thanks anyway I will just Delete the unecessary comments.

Comment: @KirillPisarev: It's just a typo I missed it If you had a look at the fiddle you will notice that I have the.push(), and you are right about the newobj wich is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not that sure what you mean but what about this

```
var obj = [];
function Obj(i){
    this.value = i;
    this.next = i+1;
}

for (var i= 0;i<10;i++){
    obj.push(new Obj(i));
}
```

Instead of an object of objects an array of them

Comment: You have a typo - `obj.push = new Obj(i)` overwrites the Array's method, instead of calling it