# Simple Jquery Ajax Get JSON data function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to create a simple little jquery function that pulls JSON data from the url, then goes through each of the objects. All I want to do is to console.log the object.name so that I know that it is working. So far it is not working :( I checked the network tab in Chrome's Developer console and in the response it shows the json data was returned. The problem is I just can't get the object.name to console.log. If someone could help point out the problem I'd be greatful.

Here is the script:

```js
function getJSON(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/api/data.json',
                success: function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(index, object){
                        console.log(object.name);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
getJSON();
```

Here is the JSON data:

```js
[
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Greg",
  lastname: "Sugaro",
  school: "Georgia Tech"

 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: "Mike",
  lastname: "Wilder",
  school: "UGA"
 }
]
```

Comment: do a `console.log(data)` before the each call and see whether that is getting called... also check your browser console to see whether any error is getting logged

Comment: @ Arun : I tried the console.log(data) before the $.each and nothing was outputted. There are no errors being logged in the bowser console.

Comment: Nothing was outputted when you did a `console.log(data)` in your success return? So you aren't getting your array of objects?

Comment: @zgood This is what is confusing me. I checked the network tab and the response shows the json data being returned from the server. For some reason I just can't get it to console.log onto the browser.

Comment: @Toshi try adding `complete: function(xhr, status){ console.log(status); }` to your ajax call after the `success` one.

Comment: Also it's worth adding an error callback and putting at least "console.log('an error occurred')".

Comment: @zgood - I tried that and I got an error: Unexpected Identifier.

Comment: @ Stephen - thanks I will add that in as well.

Comment: @Stephen - it is telling me a parse error occured... No clue...

Comment: Try adding `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: Just try

`
$.getJSON('/api/data.json',function(data){
   console.log(data);
})

`

Comment: @EternalHour - tried that and it didn't change anything...

Comment: @LMK - Nothing was outputted to the console... :-(

Comment: It shows a 'parserror' occurred so I'm assuming the browser is having trouble parsing the data... I checked the format of the JSON data and it seems like the data format is correct...

Comment: Is data `JSON` ? Should `id`, `name`, `lastname`, `school` be surrounded by double-quotes ? ; `"id"` , `"name"` , `"lastname"` , `"school"` ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json , http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @guest271314 - so it looks like the keys in JSON data must be in parenthesis.. So I changed my JSON data file to reflect this..

Answer (score 0):

When I use your JSON and `$.each` function works fine for me here's 
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gk0kkyox/)

So i guess there is some problem with your ajax call
1. either return type is not in JSON format.
2. if its json Use 
`json.stringify(data)` to see content

In previous comment you have mentioned "I tried the console.log(data) before the $.each and nothing was outputted" so that means your ajax call is not returning any response. Check your get call

Comment: Yes I think that might be it. I will try to stringify the data that is being returned... THanks

Comment: I am thinking that I need to possibly convert the JSON data into a javascript object?

Comment: Am not sure about that, as "Javascript object is a data type in Javascript - it makes sense only in Javascript". but "JSON is simply stored inside a string" To make it useful, the JSON string can be parsed to produce an object in any language. If you are okay with it go with javascript .....

Comment: @ Ashish451 - Thanks. In that case I am assuming I should use .parseJSON to convert the data to a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/api/data.json',
   success: function(data){
    objects = $.parseJSON(data)
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        console.log(objects[i].name);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

SO.... I got the code to work!! See below!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/data.json',
                    success: function(data){ 
                        console.log("success", data);
                        
                        $.each(data, function(index, object){
                            $('#data-div').append('<p>' + object.name + '</p>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```