# Are numerals valid as names in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

The following snippet executes in IE 10 JS console and in Chromes JS console.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6oq80h67/)

```
 alert({123:"ABC"}[123]);
```

However when run this through a linter (for example [jslint.com](http://jslint.com)) it complains.

When I read the documentation in [json.org](http://json.org) I understand the following 
[image]

to mean that it is incorrect to use numbers as names in a JSON object. So does this mean that at least the V8 and Chakra engine are incorrect? Or does this have something to do with strict mode(if it does, it doesn't seem to have any effect when i test it in node)?

Comment: Property names ALWAYS have to be quoted in JSON. It doesn't matter what they contain.

Comment: Your code isn't using JSON. That's a Javascript literal.

Comment: Internally those numerals will be converted into strings by it's `toString()`. So, it will be accessed fine. But it's better to use strings as property names.

Comment: If you do `JSON.parse('{123:"ABC"}')` you'll get an error.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu do you know where I could find the documentation for that?

Comment: @DanielFigueroa Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects - **An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string.**. i am trying to find one more link. Will post that soon

Comment: @Barmar Isn't it still an object, which I thought was more or less just the same as JSON?

Comment: @DanielFigueroa https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors --- Check under **Property Names**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript object Vs JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing Javascript literal syntax with JSON syntax. JSON is a restricted subset of Javascript literal syntax.

The specification of ECMAScript object initialisers can be found [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5). It contains the following production:

> ```
> PropertyName :
>     IdentifierName
>     StringLiteral
>     NumericLiteral
> ```

So a number is allowed as a property name.

Comment: Thanks! I just found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json which also explains it.

Answer (score 0):

The following would be correct:

```
var jsonString = {"123":"ABC"};
alert(jsonString[123]);
```

You have to add quotes.

You can find the documentation here http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

you can use numeric names as strings, e.g. `{"123":"ABC"}` is a valid JSON while `{123:"ABC"}` is a valid Javascript expression