# Convert Array of Object to Regular JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following array objects

```
var stats = [
    [0, 200,400], [100, 300,900],[220, 400,1000],[300, 500,1500],[400, 800,1700],[600, 1200,1800],[800, 1600,3000]
];
```

I would like to know how to convert it to the following JavaScript object.

```
var stats = [
    {x:0, y:200,k:400}, {x:100, y:300,k:900},{x:220, y:400,k:1000},{x:300, y:500,k:1500},{x:400, y:800,k:1700},{x:600, y:1200,k:1800},{x:800, y:1600,k:3000}
];
```

Comment: Note that [JSON is a text format, not the same as a JavaScrpt object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is what you need:

```
stats = stats.map(function(x) {
    return { x: x[0], y: x[1], k: x[2] };
});
```

What you describe as the desired output is not JSON, but a regular JavaScript object; if it were JSON, the key names would be in quotes.  You can, of course, convert a JavaScript object to JSON with `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map()`

```
var stats = [
    [0, 200,400], [100, 300,900],[220, 400,1000],[300, 500,1500],[400, 800,1700],[600, 1200,1800],[800, 1600,3000]
];

stats = stats.map(function(el) {
  return {
    x: el[0],
    y: el[1], 
    k: el[2]
  };
}); 

console.log(stats);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jdphenix, your answer is also correct, I have upvoted. Since Ethan answered first, I marked his answer.