# Array to json conversion using javascript in apigee

Tags: javascript, json, apigee

I have an array like this

> *["test","test group 2","test group 4","test group 4","test group 5","test group 6"]*

I need to convert this array in to json .

I have tried below code:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myArray);
```

output as like this.

> org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray@617586ce

I have tried json parsing also but did not work. 
How can I convert it to a JSON object?

Comment: what is you desired output?

Comment: My guess is that the array isn't valid; when you try and parse or stringify it, it barfs.

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please select the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code.

```
var o = '["test","test group 2","test group 4","test group 4","test group 5","test group 6"]';

var arr = JSON.stringify(o);
alert(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse(x)` to attempt to convert from a string to a javascript object.

Do NOT use eval unless you have a very specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work, try:

```
var a = JSON.parse("[\"test\",\"test group 2\",\"test group 4\",\"test group 4\",\"test group 5\",\"test group 6\"]")

console.log(a)
```

Result:

> ["test", "test group 2", "test group 4", "test group 4", "test group
>   5", "test group 6"]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a JSON object by parsing, then you need a valid JSON string. For example

```
var jsonString = "[\"test\",\"test group 2\",\"test group 4\",\"test group 4\",\"test group 5\",\"test group 6\"]";
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(jsonObject);
```

The `JSON.stringify()` method is used for conversion from an object to a string.

Check out the following links, where it's explained how to use JSON in JavaScript.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/json/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

[Javascript object Vs JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json)

Comment: Sorry it is really unclear what you're asking, without the info about excpected result.