# JavaScript Scope and objects

Tags: javascript, scope

Are there any special measures needed to pass an object from one function to another? I am relatively new to Object Oriented JavaScript so forgive me if there is an easy fix.
Here is some sample code for a problem I am having.

```
function foo {

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    /* this is the JavaScript Object that is passed in
    cell = {
            left: {x: someInt, y: someInt},
            up: {x: someInt, y: someInt},
            right: {x: someInt, y: someInt},
            down: {x: someInt, y: someInt},
            x: someInt,
            y: someInt
        }
    */    

    this.turn = function(cell){
        console.log(cell);
        processNeighbors(cell);
        smartMove(x,y, cell);

    function smartMove(x,y,cell) {
         // make a smart decision
    }

    function processNeighbors(x, y, cell) {
        console.log(cell); // this is the line of the undefined error
        // process all neighbors
    }
}
```

I expected that both outputs would be the same, however, the console.log() inside the `processNeighbors` function returns a valid response and the `bar` function returns a 'cannot read property "value" of undefined.

So when an object is passed from one function to the next, does it go out of scope? I don't change the object itself in any of functions.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this snippet you provided. I ran `new Foo().bar({value:"hello"});` and it logged `hello` twice. The only way to get your error is if `JSONObject.value` is being unset within `this.bar`. Can you post your entire code, the code that actually will get an error?

Comment: This is not a "JSON Object". It's a "JavaScript object". It's worthwhile learning this distinction. JSON is a (usually string-based) format that is used for data interchange.

Comment: If objects or any other values "went of of scope" when being passed from one function to another, then the entire web would come to a screeching halt.

Comment: JSON - JavaScript Object Notation. It's a way of representing objects in text (for storage/transmission)

Comment: "The object that I'm passed is definitely JSON" --- no it's not, it's just an object.

Comment: @zerkms and torazaburo 

Sorry for being dumb. **Thank you very much**  for  the help.
There's a good [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json) on the difference between the two that I just read.

Comment: @SeeDart - no need to apologize! The difference and relation between JSON and a JavaScript object is a very common point of confusion. Thanks for posting the link to that other thread - it should be very helpful for other people who run into the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your code again:

```
function processNeighbors(x, y, cell) {
    console.log(cell); // this is the line of the undefined error
    // process all neighbors
}
```

`processNeighbors` creates the var `cell` in the functions scope. (third argument)

So when you call `processNeighbors(cell);` the `x` parameter if your function will be cell and the `y` and `cell` parameters will be undefined.

Either remove `cell` from the arguments:

```
function processNeighbors(x, y) {
    console.log(cell);
}

// or - if that was the intended way to call the function
function processNeighbors(cell) {
    console.log(cell);
}
```

Or call it with the correct parameters:

```
processNeighbors(x,y,cell);
```

I'm not commenting on any of the other errors in your code, because I assume that those are just copy & paste mistakes.

As a really simple example:

```
var x = 10;
function fn(x) {
    alert(x);
}
function fn2() {
    alert(x);
}
fn(5); // will alert 5
fn(); // will be undefined
fn(x); // will alert 10
fn2(); // will alert 10
```

Comment: Bingo! Good catch. @SeeDart, this is the answer to your question; be sure to upvote and accept it.

Comment: Wow... That was it. Sorry my question ended up being debugging not an actual question.

Comment: Don't worry, it's always like that. If I had a dollar for every time I was on the wrong track on a debugging issue, I'd be a rich man by now!

Comment: No problem, little mistakes like that often happen. Look at how many people didn't see that problem either. Sometimes we just turn blind for the most obvious issues ;)

Comment: Why don't you make a snippet so we can run it?