# JSON Won't get events in Full Calendar from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

We're trying to load our events to Full Calendar from a URL, but the events won't load.  I've included th JS below, as well the JSON response from our URL/API.
Thanks so much!

URL/API JSON Response:

```
[{"start":"2016-04-012T15:30:00","end":"2016-04-12T16:30:00","title":"Calendar 1","allDay":"false","id":"a41380d1fbbaa819"}]
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        editable: true,
        events: {
            url: 'MY URL, I DIDN\'T POST IT HERE TO KEEP IT PRIVATE',
            error: function() {
                $('#script-warning').show();
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("successful: You can now do your stuff here. You dont need ajax. Full Calendar will do the ajax call OK? ");   
            }
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: maybe because you're entering 'URL' when you should be entering the **actual** URL where you're getting your JSON from...

Comment: Thanks for the response! Haha, I just put that so my URL wouldn't be public. @Joum

Comment: So, you're getting the JSON object back as a response when you call your URL? Does anything show up in your console?

Comment: Yes, I get the JSON object back, it just won't show up on the calendar.  I tried with a different URL and it did show the events on the calendar.  I think it has to do with formatting but can't figure it out.  Here is the other URL, http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccUKVDYErS?indent=2.  Any ideas?  Thanks! @Joum

Comment: Check if your API response (in the browser inspector's network tab, for instance) has **Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was tricky to figure out but your JSON is indeed ill-formed.

Check out the **"start"** property in you object and see how the date is written - it's *not* a Date string.

You have this:

```
2016-04-012T15:30:00
```

should be    :

```
2016-04-12T15:30:00
```

(note the highlight).

Also see this answer: [Javascript object Vs JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json)

Your problem seems to be having a JSON *string* when you need a Javascript object.

Also, see my JSBIN [here](https://jsbin.com/nalefi/edit?js) to see what's happening.

Comment: I changed the time, but it didn't fix it.  You're saying I should add the start, end, and title as objects to my API instead of JSON strings, right?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, you should be careful with your date string as it isn't in the right format.
What I'm saying regarding the response from your API is that it's sending back JSON, not object literals. This means you have to `JSON.parse()` your API response before using it in `fullcalendar` on your client.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the date format:

```
[{"start":"2016-04-012T15:30:00","end":"2016-04-12T16:30:00","title":"Calendar 1","allDay":"false","id":"a41380d1fbbaa819"}]
```

According to [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) the date "2016-04-012T15:30:00" must be changed in: "2016-04-12T15:30:00"

For more details see [start parameter in Event_Object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)