# How to change JSON String to a Javascript Object using JSON.parse for an API URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar, deployd

How can we change JSON String to a Javascript Object using JSON.parse for an API URL?

We need Full Calendar to GET events from our API URL. Our API has a JSON String, Full Calendar needs a Javascript Object, we are trying to convert it to a Javascript Object using JSON.parse
  How can we edit var javascriptObj = JSON.parse(jSonString);  with the following code to work with a URL?

Thanks so much in advance!

OUR JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    editable: true,
    events: {
        url: 'URL WE WANT TO KEEP PRIVATE',
        type: 'GET',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(resultData) {
            //here is your json.
              // process it

        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        },
    }

});

});
```

Comment: Is `resultData` already JSON and you just need to do something with it, or does it actually need to be parsed? You could give an example of the data returned and what you'd like to do with it.

Comment: You don't need to know how to parse JSON; `JSON.parse()` exists.

Comment: Thanks for the response! @Goose The JSON on the API URL needs to be parsed.

Comment: @Pointy  What would I edit to the Javascript for it to JSON.parse() the URL?  Thanks!

Comment: You may not need to do anything at all; it may be parsed already by the time your "success" callback is invoked. Add `console.log(typeof resultData)` to the top of the success function. If it logs `[object Object]` then it's already parsed.

Comment: *"parse the URL"* makes no sense. can you rephrase?

Comment: @Pointy  I'm afraid it didn't work.  Any other ideas?  Thanks again!

Comment: *What* didn't work? And what exactly does "didn't work" mean? What did you try? What happened? Errors? Weird behavior? Anything? People cannot read your mind.

Comment: @Pointy  Sorry, it didn't get any events, nothing displayed.  That's what we're trying to fix.  The JSON on our API is not in JS, so Full Calendar is not reading it.

Comment: *The JSON on our API is not in JS* - what does that even mean? Have you checked the developer console to see if any HTTP requests are happening (or even for errors)?

Comment: @Pointy  No errors, the code works to get events from other APIs formatted correctly.  I meant a Javascript object, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json

Comment: @Pointy  I edited the question, if it helps at all

Comment: "JSON.parse for an API URL" - what does this mean?!

Comment: Are you asking how to get the events from a remote api rather than having to have them in the code? because that's not at all what your question seems to be asking, but is the only thing i can think of from the mangled mess that it is plus comments. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Comment: @KevinB Sorry to all, I'm having trouble explaining it.  Here is a link to my original question, the answer explains quite well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577800/json-wont-get-events-in-full-calendar-from-url/36578907?noredirect=1#comment60790160_36578907  My issue is that our API is a JSON String, but Full Calendar can only get events from Javascript Objects, we need to do JSON.parse with our API Link, to turn the JSON String in our API link into  Javascript Object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  Sorry to all, it's been edited.  Let me know if it's any better

Comment: @IKid *"Full Calendar can only get events from Javascript Objects"* that is absolutely false. see the docs link i provided.

Comment: Why are there two questions about the same problem?

Comment: @Someone answered our question yesterday (the link provided above), saying that's what was wrong with our API content.  Do you have any idea why it wouldn't work formatted the way it is.  Thanks again. API CONTENT: [{"title":"test","start":"2016-04-13","end":"2016-04-13","id":"75bac5c63092f816"}]

Comment: @evolutionxbox The original question only solved part of the question.  I didn't understand the JSON.parse wouldn't work with a URL, the way he answered.

Comment: Why is the API result IN the url? Surely it won't be a valid URL...

Comment: Sounds like you need a middleman service on your server that will take a 3rd party json string and convert it to the format you need.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  No, that's the contents of the API, not the URL.  I just wanted to show the format

Comment: @KevinB Okay, thanks for tip!  I'm suprised Deployd doesn't do this.

Answer (score -1):

There's probably a jQuery way to do this, but here's a vanilla javascript approach.

```
    success: function(resultData) {
        var resultObject
        //here is your json.
        try {
            resultObject = JSON.parse(resultData);
        } catch(e) {
            console.error("Error parsing JSON:", e);
            throw(e);
        }

        // ... Do something with resultObject
          // process it

    },
```

Comment: You'd want to parse `resultData`, not `resultObject`.

Comment: @RayWadkins  Thanks for the response!  That didn't work for me.   Any ideas why?

Comment: This should be the correct answer if it used `JSON.parse(resultData)` instead.

Comment: Thanks Goose and evolutionxbox, typo

Answer (score -3):

if you need to change the json to javascript object you can to use "Object.create" function, this method creates a new object. check this: [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: it's hard to see how this is an answer to the (terrible) question

Comment: if you need to change the json to javascript object you can to use "Object.create" function, this method creates a new object. check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create