# How to display Json Data in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have this code where I am just trying to display a Json Data but it returns 
undefined

```
var dataW = [
        {
       empAverage:3,
       reviewerAverage:4,
       stdAverageOfTask:1
    }
]

var ReviewCalculator = React.createClass({

                            getInitialState: function() {
                                      return {data: dataW};

                              },

                          render: function() {
                              return (
                                        <table>
                                                <tr><th>empAverage</th><td>{ this.props.data.empAverage}</td></tr>
                                        </table>
                                  );

                              }
                      });
 ReactDOM.render(<ReviewCalculator    />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

The Fiddle is here [**LINK**](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/42333/)

Comment: @TheReason `dataW `  ??

Comment: [Javascript object Vs JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, because you dont have `this.props.data.empAverage` instead of that you are having `this.state.data.empAverage` & your `data` it's an array. For this example i've changed to `[0]` but for the future a suggest using `Array.prototype.map` method

Worked example

```
var dataW = [
        {
       empAverage:3,
       reviewerAverage:4,
       stdAverageOfTask:1
    }
]

var ReviewCalculator = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
     return {data: dataW};
   },
   render: function() {
     return (
        <table>
           <tr>
             <td>{this.state.data[0].reviewerAverage}</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     );

   }
});
 ReactDOM.render(<ReviewCalculator/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

You can event remove `JSON.stringify` if you want. [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/42342/)

Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/42338/ I changed but it doesnt show the value of the key instead its showing just the name

Comment: in server I am getting error , I am loading the Json from an API and it looks like this `[{"empAverage":3,"reviewerAverage":0,"stdAverageOfTask":5}]`

Comment: yes it shows error that `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Answer (score 2):

`data` is your component's 'state' set here:

```
getInitialState: function() {
 return {data: dataW};
}
```

Therefore change `this.props.data.empAverage` to `this.state.data.empAverage`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/42338/ I changed but it doesnt show the value of the key instead its showing just the name

Comment: The problem is your data. What exactly are you trying to display?

Comment: well in my Localhost I have an API which I call to update the data , the Json looks like this `[{"empAverage":3,"reviewerAverage":0,"stdAverageOfTask":5}]` and I am trying to show in a table format thats all