# How to update existing JS Object using forms - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I am converting my existing project to angularJs and there is a JS Object I that I keep update on form submit.

**autoquoteDTO.js:**

```
$.getAutoQuoteObject = function() {
  var autoQuoteObject = new autoQuote();
  autoQuoteObject.DriverVehicleInfo = new DriverVehicleInfo();
  autoQuoteObject.DriverVehicleInfo.Vehicles = [];
  autoQuoteObject.DriverVehicleInfo.Drivers = [];
  autoQuoteObject.ApplicationInfo = new ApplicationInfo();
  autoQuoteObject.ApplicationInfo.Discount = new Discount();
  autoQuoteObject.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo = new GeneralPartyInfo();
  autoQuoteObject.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo = new Contact();
  autoQuoteObject.ApplicationInfo.MostRecentInsurance = new MostRecentInsurance();
  autoQuoteObject.RequestedCoverage = new RequestedCoverage();
  autoQuoteObject.RequestedCoverage.PolicyCoverage = new PolicyCoverage();
  autoQuoteObject.RequestedCoverage.PolicyCoverage.Coverages = [];
  autoQuoteObject.RequestedCoverage.VehicleCoverage = [];
  autoQuoteObject.SessionInfo = new SessionInfo();
  return autoQuoteObject;
}

function autoQuote() {
  this.DriverVehicleInfo = null;
  this.ApplicationInfo = null;
  this.RequestedCoverage = null;
  this.SessionInfo = null;
}
var DriverVehicleInfo = function() {
  this.Drivers = [];
  this.Vehicles = [];
  this.DriverVehicleUsages = [];
};
var Driver = function() {
  this.ID = null, this.PersonInfo = null, this.DriverRelationshipToApplicant = null, this.DriverRelationshipToApplicantCd = null, this.DriverLicense = null, this.DriverDetails = [], this.Incident = null, this.IsValid = false
};
var PersonInfo = function() {
  this.FirstName = null, this.Initial = null, this.LastName = null, this.Suffix = null, this.SSN = null, this.GenderCd = null, this.BirthDate = null, this.MaritalStatusCd = null, this.OccupationClassCd = null, this.YearsOccupation = null, this.HighestEducation = null, this.AgeInYears = 0, this.SpouseLicenseStatus = null
};
var DriverLicense = function() {
  this.AgeLicense = null, this.USLicenseStatus = null, this.DriverLicenseNumber = null, this.StateProvCd = null
};
var DriverDetail = function() {
  this.DriverDetailCd = null, this.DriverDetailValue = null, this.DriverDetailDate = null
};
var Incident = function() {
  this.ClaimAccidentsCount = null, this.ViolationsCount = null, this.HasLicenseBeenRevoked = null, this.LicenseSuspensionRevokedDate = null, this.HasRequiredCourtOrderedFinancial = null, this.ClaimAccidents = [], this.Violations = [], this.DUIs = []
};
var DUI = function() {
  this.DateOfDUI = null, this.OtherValues = []
};
var ClaimAccident = function() {
  this.Id = null, this.ClaimAccidentCd = null, this.displayText = null, this.ClaimAccidentDate = null, this.DateDisplayText = null, this.Comprehensive = null, this.Collision = null, this.RentalReimbursement = null, this.MedicalPayment = null, this.PayToOtherParty = null, this.IsInjury = null, this.IsPropertyDamage = null
};
var Violation = function() {
  this.Id = null, this.ViolationCd = null, this.ViolationDate = null, this.displayText = null
};
var Vehicle = function() {
  this.ID = null, this.VehicleHaveVin = false, this.VehicleIdentificationNumber = null, this.VehicleYear = null, this.VehicleMake = null, this.VehicleModel = null, this.VehicleSubModel = null, this.AntiLockBrakeCd = null, this.AntiTheftDeviceCd = null, this.VehicleUseCd = null, this.NumDaysDrivenPerWeek = null, this.DistanceOneWay = null, this.EstimatedAnnualDistance = null, this.OwnershipCd = null, this.RegistrationStateProvCd = null, this.VehIdentificationNumber = null, this.IsCustomizedOrAltered = null, this.OriginalVehicleCost = null, this.IsValid = false, this.VehicleType = null, this.VehicleVinStub = null, this.ShowVehicleAntiLockBrakeInfo = false, this.VehicleCost = null, this.ShowVehicleCost = false, this.DaytimeLights = null
};
var DriverVehicleUsage = function() {
  this.DriverIDRef = null, this.VehicleIDRef = null, this.Usage = null
};
var ApplicationInfo = function() {
  this.GeneralPartyInfo = null, this.Discount = null, this.MostRecentInsurance = null, this.ConsumerContactAuth = null, this.ConsumerInfoAuthorization = null, this.ConsumerContactMobileAuth = null
};
var GeneralPartyInfo = function() {
  this.MainApplicantDriverIDRef = null, this.Address = null, this.PreviousAddress = null, this.ContactInfo = null, this.ResidenceInfo = null, this.ListedVehiclesRegisteredTo = null, this.CreditScore = 0
};
var AddressInfo = function() {
  this.Address = null, this.City = null, this.State = null, this.PostalCode = null, this.County = null
};
var PreviousAddress = function() {
  this.Address = null, this.City = null, this.State = null, this.PostalCode = null, this.County = null
};
var Contact = function() {
  this.Phones = [], this.Emails = []
};
var Email = function() {
  this.EmailTypeCd = null, this.EmailAddress = null
};
var Phone = function() {
  this.PhoneTypeCd = null, this.PhoneNumber = null
};
var Residence = function() {
  this.LengthAtCurrentAddressCd = null, this.ResidenceTypeCd = null, this.NumberDriversInHouseHold = null, this.VehiclesRegistedToInsured = null, this.DriverResidentsFromFL = null, this.CityLimits = null
};
var Discount = function() {
  this.ResidentialInsurancePolicy = null, this.OwnBoat = null, this.OwnMotorCycle = null, this.IsAAAMember = null
};
var MostRecentInsurance = function() {
  this.HasAutoInsurance = null, this.InsuranceCompanyName = null, this.CurrentInsurancePaying = null, this.LengthWithCurrentInsuranceCd = null, this.BodilyInjuryLiabilityLimit = null, this.LengthContinuouslyInsuredCd = null, this.ExpirationDate = null, this.InsuranceCanceledForNonPay = null, this.ClaimDeniedDueToFraud = null
};
var RequestedCoverage = function() {
  this.EffectiveDate = null, this.StateCd = null, this.PolicyCoverage = null, this.VehiclesCoverage = []
};
var PolicyCoverage = function() {
  this.Coverages = []
};
var Coverage = function() {
  this.CoverageCd = null, this.CoverageValue = null
};
var VehicleCoverage = function() {
  this.IsValid = false, this.VehicleIDRef = null, this.Coverages = []
};
var SessionInfo = function() {
  this.SessionId = '', this.SecurityToken = '', this.Zip = '', this.StateCode = '', this.PageName = '', this.PageTheme = '', this.CarrierId = -1, this.ReturnedCarrierTypes = null, this.CoveragePackage = '', this.UseExistingSession = false, this.QuoteStatus = '', this.SID = -1, this.SRC = null, this.SRC_QCP = null, this.Referral = null, this.ClientIP = null, this.BrowserType = null, this.CLK = 0, this.QTR = '', this.CCID = '', this.AFF = '', this.PreviousSessionId = '', this.IgnoreErrors = false, this.RetrieveSource = '', this.PreviousPageName = ''
}
```

**prapareJson.js:**

```
var prepareAutoQuoteDTO = {
    postAutoQuoteObj: $.getAutoQuoteObject(),  
    initializeDriverObj: function()
    {
        var driverLocObj           = new Driver();
        driverLocObj.PersonInfo    = new PersonInfo();
        driverLocObj.DriverLicense = new DriverLicense();
        driverLocObj.Incident      = new Incident();
        return driverLocObj;
    },

    initializeAppInfo: function()
    {
        var appInfoLocObj           = new ApplicationInfo();
        appInfoLocObj.Discount      = new Discount();
        return appInfoLocObj;

    },
    /*
    * Initialize Vehicle object for autoQuoteDTO.js
    */
    initializeVehicleObj: function()
    {
        var vehicleLocObj = new Vehicle();
        return vehicleLocObj;
    },

    rc1Step1DTO: function()
    {
       /*
        * store session info
        */
        var emailId = $('#save_quote_email').val();
        if (typeof emailId  !== "undefined" && emailId && emailId != '' && emailId != 'Email Address')
        {
            var email           = new Email();
            email.EmailTypeCd   = 'PRIMARY';
            email.EmailAddress  = emailId;
            this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo = this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo || new Contact();
            this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails = [];
            this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails.push(email);
        }
};
```

**update json on user event code:**

```
prepareAutoQuoteDTO.rc1Step1DTO();
```

**The new Angular JS code that should update the JS Object:**

```
 (function(){
    "use strict";
    angular
    .model("autoQuote")
    .controller("prepareDTO","prepareDTO")
    .controller("postDTO","postDTO");
        /*
         * Call actions on page load
         */
    var init = function () {
                 prepareDTO();    
        }
        init();

        /*
         * prepare DTO with form elements.
         */
        function prepareDTO()
    {
         var vm = this;
         vm.postAutoQuoteObj = [];   
    }

        /*
         * post DTO on form submit and page onload.
         */
        function postDTO()
        {

        }     

 });
```

The form logic should be contained in the `prepareDTO` funtion.

**The expected behavior** is if step1 form is submitted, then `rc1Step1DTO` should be called and JS data should be saved.

Looking for suggestions to achieve this and best practices.

Plunker of my complete code is http://plnkr.co/edit/VJKrDRMJY3Q73bsCgVwX?p=preview.

I can remove/edit this file and everything in Angular JS but lie stuck how to do that in AngularJS.

Comment: There is not enough information, what are you trying to do : create a form in the angular way and post the data to your server on submit ? If so you should check "angularjs form sample" on the net such question doesn't fit on SO.

Comment: I added a json in which I was adding information on ui onload or form submit. I just want to know how to use such json in angualr js. I want add prepareAutoQuoteDTO in autoQuote model.

Comment: You're mistunderstanding JSON and Javascript Object, JSON is a seralization format, it's a huge string in a specific format used between different programs to exchange information. WHat you have here are just normal Javascript object, if you pass the objects into a $htt.post, angularJS will transform them to JSON automatically. This happen often because the Javascript syntax when declaring multiple level object is exactle the same as the JSON format.

Comment: Here i added prapareJson.js file where I maintain json data. how can i creta sam in angular js

Comment: As i said, it's not JSON, you instantiated Javascript Objects. So it's exactly the same in angular.

Comment: Check this link to understand the difference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json

Comment: How to convert now my project to angulat js. i am beginner to angular js and need some suggestion.

Comment: added prepareAutoQuoteDTO.js to plunkr, what I want to achieve here is if step1 form is submitted rc1Step1DTO should be called and json should save that data.

Comment: Are you sure `.model("autoQuote")` is correct? Shouldn't it be `.module("autoQuote")` ?

Comment: it is module. thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2):

You can move all your code into a factory, and then inject it into a controller.
All your other dependencies (like `Driver`) must be included before this executes or could be even declared in `prepareDtoFactory` function.

```
angular
.model("autoQuote")
.controller(dtoController)
.factory(prepareDtoFactory);

function dtoController(prepareDtoFactory){
     prepareDtoFactory.rc1Step1DTO(); //call function from your service, and do something with it
}

dtoController.$inject = ['prepareDtoFactory'];

function prepareDtoFactory(){

    var prepareAutoQuoteDTO = {
        postAutoQuoteObj         : $.getAutoQuoteObject(),  
        initializeDriverObj: function(){
            var driverLocObj           = new Driver();
            driverLocObj.PersonInfo    = new PersonInfo();
            driverLocObj.DriverLicense = new DriverLicense();
            driverLocObj.Incident      = new Incident();
            return driverLocObj;
       },
       initializeAppInfo: function(){
           var appInfoLocObj           = new ApplicationInfo();
           appInfoLocObj.Discount      = new Discount();
           return appInfoLocObj;
       },
       /*
       * Initialize Vehicle object for autoQuoteDTO.js
       */
       initializeVehicleObj: function(){
           var vehicleLocObj = new Vehicle();
           return vehicleLocObj;
       },
       /*
       * store session info
       */
       rc1Step1DTO: function(){

            var emailId = $('#save_quote_email').val();
            if (typeof emailId  !== "undefined" && emailId && emailId != '' && emailId != 'Email Address'){
                var email           = new Email();
                email.EmailTypeCd   = 'PRIMARY';
                email.EmailAddress  = emailId;
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo =     this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo || new Contact();
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails = [];
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails.push(email);
            }
        }
    };
    return prepareAutoQuoteDTO;
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful suggestion. Here in step1 and step2 I have form with inputs. when I submit this form I want to call dtoController and send this data to server(api) to save. How to call this function and send data to server.

Comment: Complete code can be seen here http://plnkr.co/edit/VJKrDRMJY3Q73bsCgVwX?p=preview

Comment: Getting error when I included your code. Error [$injector:pget] Provider 'function prepareDtoFactory()' must define $get factory method.

Answer (score 0):

following the AJS [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="prepareDTO as pdt">
  <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="pdt.user.email" /><br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="pdt.reset()" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="pdt.update(user)" value="Save" />
  </form>
  <pre>user = {{user | json}}</pre>

</div>
```

**app.js**

```
function prepareDTO()
    {
         var vm = this;

         vm.user = {
           email: ''
         };

         vm.update = function(user){
           prepareAutoQuoteDTO.rc1Step1DTO(user.email);

         }
    }
```

please note that `prepareAutoQuoteDTO.rc1Step1DTO` in order to avoid errors should be modified as:

```
rc1Step1DTO: function(email)
    {
       /*
        * store session info
        */
        var emailId = email;
        if (typeof emailId  !== "undefined" && emailId && emailId != '' && emailId != 'Email Address')
        {
            var email           = new Email();
            email.EmailTypeCd   = 'PRIMARY';
            email.EmailAddress  = emailId;
            this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo = this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo || new Contact();
            this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails = [];
            this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails.push(email);
       }
}
```