# NodeJS and PDFkit: 'margin' property gives "Unexpected identifier" error?

Tags: node.js, pdf, coffeescript, pdfkit

I have successfully gotten my code to output a pdf, but when I attempt to adjust the margins using the 'margin' property listed in the [documentation](http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html#adding_pages) using the following code,

```
var pdf = require ('pdfkit');
var fs = require('fs');

var doc = new pdf(
{
    size: [288,144]

}
);

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('run.pdf'));

doc.font('Times-Roman')
   .text('Hello different Times Roman!')

doc.addPage({
    size: [288,144]
    margin : 10
});

doc.end();
```

I get this error:

```
margin : 10
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: It's JSON, just include a comma after `size: [288,144]`.

Comment: @Dandy This worked! Thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to ensure any future reader come here with this specific problem, this is a JavaScript Object. When listing JavaScript Objects, every property must be followed by a `,` except the last instance.

As an example, this:

```
doc.addPage({
    size: [288,144]
    margin : 10
});
```

becomes this:

```
doc.addPage({
    size: [288,144], 
    margin : 10
});
```

Comment: This is a little pedantic, but it's not JSON, it's a JavaScript Object. It would be JSON if it were encoded as a string  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json). But the same formatting and syntax applies, so the problem was still solved. +1