# Incorrect return Json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json in a local file:

```
    {
   "fields": {

    "input": {
        "name": "txtCpf",
        "id": "txtCpf",
        "value": "",
        "type": "text",
        "Mask": "000.000.000-00",
        "class": "input"
    },
    "input": {
        "name": "txtTelephone",
        "id": "txtTelefone",
        "value": "",
        "type": "text",
        "Mask": "(00) 00000-0000",
        "class": "input"
    },

    "button": {
        "name": "btnSave",
        "id": "btnSave",
        "value": "",
        "class": "input"
        }
   }
}
```

This is my javascript code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.fields.input.name;

        Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(myObj.fields.input);

        });
        /* myObj.foreach(function(input){
             var fields = input.fields;
             alert(fields);
         }); */



    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "mock.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This `myObj.fields.input.name` is returning only the last position of the `input` object so it shows **txtTelephone**

Would like a return of all objects of the input and not only of the last element

Using javascript only..

Comment: yours json incorrect, `inputs` must be into array

Comment: To rephrase slightly differently: you can't have duplicate keys in a JS object. Or a JSON object.

Comment: You cannot have a duplicated key in a JSON, try JSONLint online tool

Comment: As @GeorgeVassilev has written, you're [JSON is invalid](https://jsonlint.com/) as it contains a duplicate key. I believe your data structure should be `{"fields:[{"name": "txtTelephone", ect}]}`

Comment: Actually technically duplicate keys are still considered valid JSON, although is highly discouraged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JSON syntax allow duplicate keys in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object)

Comment: Let's be clear: [JSON Objects do not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json). It's either JSON (a string), or an object.

Comment: @chazsolo How is that? Ofcourse [JSON object exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) = ).

Comment: The problem is that this json file has been passed on to me and I can not change it.
Is it really not possible?
By no means can the "Input" key be repeated?

Answer (score 3):

Correct json to :

```
{
    "fields": {
        "input": [{
                "name": "txtCpf",
                "id": "txtCpf",
                "value": "",
                "type": "text",
                "Mask": "000.000.000-00",
                "class": "input"
            },
            {
                "name": "txtTelephone",
                "id": "txtTelefone",
                "value": "",
                "type": "text",
                "Mask": "(00) 00000-0000",
                "class": "input"
            }
        ],
        "button": {
            "name": "btnSave",
            "id": "btnSave",
            "value": "",
            "class": "input"
        }
    }
}
```

to retrieve all input names, change your script to:

```
myObj.fields.input.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item.name);
})
```

Comment: That still does not answer the question: How to **retrieve** all the names?

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht I'm guessing ones the Json is fixed the current JavaScript will do that already.

Comment: @Fran nope, not in its current form.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht I didn't realize that OP still has issue getting the items ones the Json is fixed. You should post a complete answer then I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not correct,
You can't have with a json object 2 keys identical (input)
If there is 2 identicals keys; the first one is overwritten with the last one.

Convert it to an array for example or change your key name.