# Check for a value in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I found some posts related but i cant make it work.

I have a variable:

```
var object = {id: "4", black: false, destacado: ""};
```

I need to make an if that makes something if "black" is true.

Comment: `if(object.black) { … }`

Comment: That's not JSON

Comment: FYI [Javascript object Vs JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json). JSON is a **String** (`""`) notation. What you have there is just a JS object

Comment: "I found some posts related but i cant make it work" — What have you tried? What happened when you did? Try providing a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks. Ill learn more about javascript object and json differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
if (object.black === true) {
    // do your thing
}
```

Using `===` ensures that it is `true` and not some other truthy value.