# Retrieve a value from json array response in angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm able to get all users with their roles from the backend laravel.
This is the response.

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "user",
        "last_name": "xyz",
        "title": null,
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "phone_number": "***-***-****",
        "phone_type": "home",
        "inactive": 0,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "is_verified": 0,
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Account User",
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 2,
                    "role_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

I'm retrieving the users data like this

in ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<User>('backend.url')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

in html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let userData of user?.users; trackBy: userThumb">
                <td>{{ userData?.first_name }}</td>
```

Now, I want to show the role name of the user in a frontend table.
How do I retrieve the **roles->name** in angular 4 from this users array?

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(response);` And then you could use obj.users[0].roles[0].name

Comment: What exactly is the desired result? An array with all the `name`s (excluding duplicates?) of all the `roles` of all the `users`?

Comment: try it like this : text.users[0].roles[0].name

Comment: I edited the question. Please check

Comment: Can there be multiple roles for a user ?

Comment: It's not a _JSON_ it's a javascript object! [`JSON vs js object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @yer but the edit doesn't change anything. This has nothing to do with any of Angular, Laravel, or JSON. It is just standard JavaScript syntax for accessing properties.

Comment: @TheReason thank you, sir!

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let userData of user?.users; trackBy: userThumb">
                <td>{{ userData?.roles[0].name
}} </td>

Comment: Yeah, there can be multiple roles for a user @Niladri

Comment: @yer add another *ngFor for the roles

Comment: @ZohidSaidov thanks! Could you tell me without using index on roles because there will multiple users with multiple roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look this:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let userData of user?.users; trackBy: userThumb"> 
    <td *ngFor="let role of userData ?.roles; > {{role ?.name}}</td> 
 </tr>
```