# Passing JSON from NodeJS to R using r-script

Tags: r, node.js

I am trying to setup a simple connect between a NodeJS application and an R-script.
So far I've managed to set up the basic connection and the running of the cript, by using `r-script` (found on npm).

However, I am not able to pass a simple json to the R so that it can be converted to a dataframe using `jsonlite`.

NodeJS Code:

```
var R = require("r-script");

var out = R("script.R")
  .data({"Name" : "Mario", "Age" : 32, "Occupation" : "Plumber"},  {"Name" : "Peach", "Age" : 21, "Occupation" : "Princess"}, {}, {"Name" : "Bowser", "Occupation" : "Koopa"})
  .callSync();

console.log(out);
```

script.R:

```
library("jsonlite")
mydf <- fromJSON(input[[1]])
```

This gives the output:

```
 'Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.'
```

I have tried removing the indexation of the vector (and give the full list to the fromJSON) but it also doesn't work.

Has anyone sucessfully passed JSON to an R script with this npm module?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Also, if place the JSON between "'", it gives me "trailing errors" in spaces, and if they are removed, on the { char.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about how R works, however the error could point to the fact that what you are trying to pass is a javascript object, not a JSON. Javascript objects look like but are not identical to JSONs (see discussion here [Javascript object Vs JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json))

One thing that you can try is passing in the data function a JSON string by calling the JSON.stringify function on your objects. Something like this:

```
var R = require("r-script");

var out = R("script.R")
  .data(JSON.stringify({"Name" : "Mario", "Age" : 32, "Occupation" : "Plumber"}), JSON.stringify( {"Name" : "Peach", "Age" : 21, "Occupation" : "Princess"}),JSON.stringify ({}), JSON.stringify({"Name" : "Bowser", "Occupation" : "Koopa"}))
  .callSync();

console.log(out);
```

It's a longshot but it shows a general direction on which you can debug

Answer (score 1):

I managed to found a simple solution, the Manos Agelidis answer did put me in the right direction.

Basically, I have able to parse the input string using:

```
string = paste(input, collapse=",") 
string = paste("[",string,"]")
frame = fromJSON(string)
```

and in NodeJS:

```
  var out = R("script.R")
  .data('{"Name":"Mario","Age":32,"Occupation":"Plumber"}',
  '{"Name":"Peach","Age":21,"Occupation":"Princess"}',
  '{}',
  '{"Name":"Bowser","Occupation":"Koopa"}')
  .callSync();
```

`fromJSON` requires a vector but in string form, and not a literal vector. Therefore, what I needed to do what to create a string using the elements of the `input` and to add `[` and `]` to the begging and end of the string, respectively. This did convert to a data frame properly.