# Is it not possible to store function as JSON key value in .json file in angular 5

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

We have an Angular 5 project in which we have a `.json` file which we're loading in a `.ts` file using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).

The `.json` file have the following content:

```
{
    stringKey: "stringValue",
    functionKey: function() {
        console.log('function called!')
    }
}
```

It throws the error: `[json] value expected`

[image: json value expected]

If I open Chrome Devtool and set the above object as value - it works fine but not in the project

```js
var obj = {
  stringKey: "stringValue",
  functionKey: function() {
    console.log('function called!')
  }
}

obj.functionKey();
```

**Edit:**

Is there a work around for storing functions in pure JSON?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json

Comment: Not possible. JSON values can only be scalars and literal object or array declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if that helps (`functionKey` needs to be a `string`, you would then use `eval` to get result)

```
var obj =  {
stringKey : "stringValue",
functionKey: "(function() { console.log('function called')})()"
}

var result = eval(obj.functionKey);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/spdr80c7/

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a function inside a json file because it is a data format language,
but you can do it in a js file with a JS Object like you did:

```
var obj = {
  functionKey: function() {
    console.log('function called!')
  }
}
obj.functionKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function data type in JSON.

See [the documentation](http://json.org/). JSON supports objects, arrays, strings, numbers, booleans and null.

It is a data format, not a programming language. It doesn't make much sense for it to support functions.

Comment: How is it possible in DevTool console then?

Comment: @student — Because that is JavaScript (which **is** a programming language) and not JSON.

Comment: Looking clear to me, so how do I handle this scenario then? Any suggestions please?

Comment: Store your functions in your program. Use the data in your data file to decide which functions to call.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, For my specific project needs - I still need some work around for storing functions in JSON. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
  stringKey: "stringValue",
  functionKey: function() {
    console.log('function called!')
  }
}

obj.functionKey();
```

Here you are just creating an Object `obj` not JSON.

Just try to convert this Object to JSON using `JSON.stringify(obj)` it will remove the functionKey as its not a string.