# why does it not update the sql row in the react web application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sqlite, express, axios

I am building a web application by using react, axios as front end, and sqlite, express, nodejs as the back end.

I am trying to search a student from the server and database, and then modify the name of the student.  However, although I made sure my backend should be alright by using postman, it still does not update the row I selected.  And I also made sure the object I passed to the server is an object containing only `studentId` and `firstName` by using `console.log`.

This is my react javascript
It has two main function:

1. `handleSearch`: Search the student by using the `searchId` from the user
2. `handleModifyFirstName`: Modify the student first name based on the `studentId`, and this is the function that does not work.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const SearchStudent = () => {
  const [searchId, setSearchId] = useState("");
  const [studentsList, setStudentsList] = useState([]);
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");

  const handleSearch = () => {
    const newSearchId = searchId;
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/students/" + newSearchId)
      .then((response) => {
        setStudentsList(response.data.row);
      });
    setSearchId("");
    setStudentsList([]);
  };

  const handleModifyFirstName = (studentId) => {
    const data = { studentId, firstName };
    window.alert(data);
    console.log(data);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/students/modifyFirstName/", data)
      .then((response) => {
        var resData = response.data;
        let data = JSON.stringify(resData);
        window.alert("Response recieved from server = " + data);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="searchId"
          name="searchId"
          value={searchId}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchId(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
      </form>
      <button onClick={handleSearch}>search</button>
      {studentsList.map((data) => (
        <div key={data.studentId}>
          <h4>first Name: {data.firstName}</h4>
          <p>second name: {data.lastName}</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            value={firstName}
            onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
          ></input>
          <button onClick={() => handleModifyFirstName(data.studentId)}>
            edit first name
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchStudent;
```

This is the `server.js`

```
var express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var db = require("./database.js");

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var HTTP_PORT = 8080;

app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port %PORT%".replace("%PORT%", HTTP_PORT));
});

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ message: "Ok" });
});


app.post("/students/modifyFirstName/", (req, res, next) => {
 //this is the SQL query that should work
  const sql = 'UPDATE students SET firstName =? WHERE studentId =?';
  const params = [req.query["firstName"], req.query["studentId"]];
  // const params = [data.firstName, data.studentId];
  db.run(sql, params, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
      return;
    }
     res.json({
     message: "success",
     data: data,
     id: this.lastID,
     });
  });
});
```

This is the `database.js`

```
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database("students.db", (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("Connected to the students database.");
});

const sql =
  "CREATE TABLE students (firstName text, lastName text, studentId text) ";

db.run(sql, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Table already created.");
  } else {
    console.log("Table created.");

    console.log("First time Table created, creating some rows.");

    var insert =
      "INSERT INTO students (firstName, lastName, studentId) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    db.run(insert, ["hellow", "world1", "1"]);
    db.run(insert, ["hellow", "world2", "2"]);
    db.run(insert, ["some", "value", "3"]);
  }
});

module.exports = db;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server.js file you should be using req.body because you are sending a JSON object. req.query is used for the query string within the URL.

```
const params = [req.body["firstName"], req.body["studentId"]];
```

Comment: To answer your previous question, you cannot send a JavaScript object over an HTTP request without converting it into JSON first. In your React code, Axios converts your JavaScript object into a string in the JSON format. When you make a POST request to your API, the express body-parser parses the JSON string back into a JavaScript object that you can use access at req.body. 

Read this for a more detailed explaination:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json