# Can't convert response to json using res.json()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I request to server and get response as expected(I'm writing react app). In network tab ([network tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ2xo.png)) you see response is properly formatted to json.
But when I console log answer with code below I see nothing:

```
fetch("http://192.168.20.81:8301/market/housing/home_price/", {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Data: ", data);
      });
```

Also I get this error in console of firefox:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Comment: Does the raw response data look valid too? No trailing characters perhaps?

Comment: FYI, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header, it's not something you can configure from the request. It's up to the server to add that header to the response.

Comment: @robertklep It's valid

Comment: @Lennholm If I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to header from server; can I see it in browser response header?

Answer (score 0):

I think your data fetch from server which is json format.
Please try it as below. I think it is ok

```js
fetch("http://192.168.20.81:8301/market/housing/home_price/", {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    })
      .then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      console.log(data)
     }
     .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Comment: That's not how `fetch` works.

Comment: You'll need to parse it into object literals first like OP's, then you can access property with dot notation. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8294198/16648127)