# cannot add hours to JSON

Tags: reactjs, json

I need to use a TimePicker component in my React app to allow users to select hours and minutes. After the user selects a time, I want to display the selected hours and minutes in the console when the user clicks a button. However, when I test my code, I can only see the selected minutes in the console. I'm using React and Bootstrap to create this functionality. Can you please advise me on how to fix this issue?

```
import TimePicker from 'react-times';

function TimePickerExample(props) {
    const { selectedTime, setSelectedTime } = props;
    const [time, setTime] = useState({ hour: 0, minute: 0 });

    const handleTimeChange = (newTime) => {
        setTime(newTime);
        setSelectedTime(newTime);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="time">Choose time</label>
            <TimePicker
                theme="material"
                colorPalette="light"
                time={time}
                onTimeChange={handleTimeChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
function Send(props) {
    const { selectedTime } = props;

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            selectedTime: `${selectedTime.hour}:${selectedTime.minute}`,
        };
        const newJsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

        console.log(newJsonData);
    };
    return (
        <div className="send">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Send
                </Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
function App() {
    const handleTimeChange = (time) => {
        setSelectedTime(time);
    };
    const handleClear = () => {
        setSelectedTime(null);
    };
    return (
        <div className="choose">
            <TimePickerExample selectedTime={selectedTime} setSelectedTime={handleTimeChange} />
            <div className="buttons-row">
                <Send
                    selectedTime={selectedTime}
                />
                <Clear onClear={handleClear} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json

Comment: What is `setSelectedTime` in `App`? You never declared it