# Difference between JSON and SBJSON?

Tags: json, sbjson

- Can anyone tell me the difference between json and sbjson?
- What is the use of these two?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

JSON and SBJSON cannot be compared because one is a standard/protocol, and the other is a language-specific implementation made to use that standard.

[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) stands for Javascript Object Notation. It is just a standard for transmitting data (similar to XML, but more lightweight). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it?rq=1) answer for some more info.

[SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) is one of the many open-source json parsers/generators created with Objective-C. Some other ones are touchJSON and JSONKit. These allow you to use JSON easily when coding Objective-C apps.

As of iOS 5, there is a built in class called [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do this for you. If you want to support any iOS version prior to iOS 5, you will need to use something like one of the previously mentioned frameworks.

In any environment, you would typically use JSON for transmitting/receiving data from a remote source, such as a [RESTFUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web service.

Answer (score 1):

SBJson is a json framework for ios/iphone.

Answer (score -1):

**SBJson** is a data interchange formatter that's easy to read and write.It's one kind of JSON. This framework is supported by IOS.

Where as **JSON** means JavaScript Object Notation.It is syntax for storing and exchanging information or data.