# Actionresult vs JSONresult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, jsonresult

**I have 2 questions:**

> 1. What is the difference between JSONResult and ActionResult?
> 2. When to use JSONResult in MVC?

Comment: you should see that question man :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it

Answer (score 39):

`ActionResult` is an abstract class that an action can return.

The helper methods in `Controller` (eg, `Json()`, `Content()`, `View()`, ...) return different concrete classes that inherit `ActionResult`, including `JsonResult`.

You should declare your action methods as returning `ActionResult`, so that they have the freedom to return any concrete result class.

Comment: [MSDN lists the different concrete implementations of ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: `You should declare your action methods as returning ActionResult, so that they have the freedom to return any concrete result class` I disagree. You should be specific as possible about return types, and as general as possible for arguments. `JsonResult` is the proper type to return in most cases, as other methods may use the method and want to inspect `.Data` which is only exposed in `JsonResult`.

Comment: @Rob: You should not call action methods directly.  If you need to expose a value to other code, move it to a helper method.

Comment: @SLaks While I agree in general that it might be worthy of a helper method, it's entirely acceptable for a test to call the method directly. If you define your method as returning JSON, and one day you decide to return XML, you'll catch it *early* via tests. Or you might think twice about changing an API which used to always return JSON. It's a bit of a code smell to return either `View()` or `Json()` on the same controller method. Return types should always be specific, whether or not they should be called directly.

Answer (score 20):

Use `JsonResult` when you want to return raw JSON data to be consumed by a client (javascript on a web page or a mobile client).

Use `ActionResult` if you want to return a view, redirect etc to be handled by a browser.

Answer (score 5):

`ActionResult` is an *abstract class* .`JsonResult` is subtype of `ActionResult`. So we can return json content in both types.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for the `ActionResult`:

> The ActionResult class Encapsulates the result of an action method and
>   is used to perform a framework-level operation on behalf of the action
>   method.
>
> An action method responds to user input by performing work and
>   returning an action result. An action result represents a command that
>   the framework will perform on behalf of the action method. The
>   ActionResult class is the base class for action results

And for [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

> Represents a class that is used to send JSON-formatted content to the
>   response.

Answer (score 1):

> **JsonResult**
>
> This one is a bit more complex, but still not very. It also has
>   hardcoded its ContentType, but what makes it a bit more complex is
>   that it uses a hardcoded JavaScriptSerializer to serialize the JSON
>   data before writing it directly to the response.

this post can be helpful
http://brendan.enrick.com/post/types-of-aspnet-mvc-3-action-results.aspx