# Should I specify an specific ActionResult or use the abstract class in my ASP.NET MVC AJAX methods?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, return-type, actionresult

If I have an action method that I know it will only be called via AJAX and always returning JSON...

Do I set the method return type to `JsonResult` or leave it to `ActionResult`?

Please explain the reason of the choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare your action methods as returning `ActionResult`, so that they have the freedom to return any concrete result class.

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15250991/7720

Comment: Yes but, do I want that freedom if I know for sure I'm expecting a JsonResult?

Comment: If you are sure that the return result is JSON you dont have to specify `ActionResult`. Although jsonresult inherits actionresult so it doesnt matter! Note you can return simple string as well from an Action