# Convert Javascript string or array into JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JavaScript variable with comma separated string values - i.e. `value1,value2,value3, ......,valueX,`

I need to convert this variable's values into a JSON object. I will then use this object to match user enteredText value by using `filterObj.hasOwnProperty(search)`

Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: As there is no such thing as a "Json object", it's hard to get what you want. Maybe you should look at [what is JSON](http://www.json.org/) ?

Comment: You can match entered text by just doing `str.indexOf(search) != -1`

Answer (score 3):

What you seem to want is to build, from your string, a JavaScript object that would act as a map so that you can efficiently test what values are inside.

You can do it like this :

```
var str = 'value1,value2,value3,valueX';
var map = {};
var tokens = str.split(',');
for (var i=tokens.length; i--;) map[tokens[i]]=true;
```

Then you can test if a value is present like this :

```
if (map[someWord]) {
    // yes it's present
}
```

Comment: thank you guys. You really save my click. Your solutions are working for me. thank you again.

Comment: Dude. `for (var i = tokens.length; i--;)`, really? Even `while` is more readable.

Comment: Well. It saved a click. You can't argue against that.

Answer (score 2):

Why JSON? You can convert it into an array with `split(",")`.

```
var csv = 'value1,value2,value3';
var array = csv.split(",");
console.log(array); // ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

Accessing it with `array[i]` should do the job.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // do anything you want with array[i]
}
```

[JSON is used for data interchanging.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it) Unless you would like to communicate with other languages or pass some data along, there is no need for JSON when you are processing with JavaScript on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has **JSON.stringify()** method to convert an object into JSON string and similarly **JSON.parse()** to convert it back. Read more about it

> [All about JSON : Why & How](http://www.cheezycode.com/2016/07/how-to-create-json-what-is-json.html)

Cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

JSON format requires (single or multi-dimensional) list of key, value pairs. You cannot just convert a comma separated list in to JSON format. You need keys to assign.

Example,

```
[
  {"key":"value1"},
  {"key":"value2"},
  {"key":"value3"},
  ...
  {"key":"valueX"}
]
```

I think for your requirement, you can use Array.

Comment: ["value1", "value2", "value3"] is a valid JSON array