# Accessing the content of a parsed JSON text

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am reading an http request containing JSON and parsing it like this:

```
res = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText)
```

The result of my request is:

```
{"node":[{"id":"10","name":"a_name"}], "childs":[{"id":"11"}]}
```

How can I access to the attribute `childs` in javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects

Comment: `res.childs`, `res['childs']`

Comment: by reading a basic javascript tutorial, or at least a cheat sheet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is JSON and why would I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the attributes like it:

```
res.childs[0].id;
```

this will give the output:

```
11
```

Similarly you can access other attributes.

Comment: `res.childs[0].id;` gives `11`

Comment: @PrasathK ok, thanks I have modified it.

Answer (score 1):

The resulting JSON is accessible as a regular JavaScript object (that's one of the cool things about JSON) and you can access them as you would a regular JavaScript object.

For example:

```
var res = JSON.parse('{"node":[{"id":"10","name":"a_name"}], "childs":[{"id":"11"}]}');
console.log(res.childs);
```