# AJAX Autocomplete not showing suggestions values in test box

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery

Autocomplete not showing the suggestion values in text box. but back end query executed and got the results, it's not showing up in the text box. Please advise me how to showup the suggestionsbox in the text field.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Complete in JSP Java</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#names").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "searchName.jsp",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    data: { name: request.term},
    success: function( data ) {
    //alert(data);

        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
        return {
            label: item.name,
            value: item.value,
        }
        }));
    },
    error: function (error) {
       alert('error: ' + error);
    }
    });
    },
    minLength: 3
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="name" id="names" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

searchnames.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

   <%
  String query = (String)request.getParameter("name");
   try{
     String s[]=null;
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     Connection con DriverManager.getConnection("XXXX");
     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select name from Table1 where name like '"+query+"%'");
     List li = new ArrayList();
     while(rs.next())
       {
         li.add(rs.getString(1));
       }

      String[] str = new String[li.size()];
      Iterator it = li.iterator();
      int i = 0;
       while(it.hasNext())
       {
           String p = (String)it.next();
           str[i] = p;
           i++;
       }

       int cnt=1;
       for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
       {
           if(str[j].toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
           {
              out.print(str[j]+"\n");
              if(cnt>=5)// 5=How many results have to show while we are typing(auto suggestions)
              break;
              cnt++;
            }
       }

rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();

}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}


%>
```

Please advise me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems  your  .jsp is not outputting json format. you would need to change this  line

```
out.print(str[j]+"\n");
```

to

```
out.print("\"name\" : " + "\"" + str[j]+"\"\n");
```

and then in your javascript code

```
response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
    return {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.name,
    }
    }));
```

see [more about JSON format here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it/383699#383699)

for informative purposes I'm concatenating Strings with operator +, try to use StringBuilder for better performance.