# What is the JSON objects

Tags: json

In the official Java EE tutorial said that JSON defines six data types: string, number, object, array, true, false and null. Consider the following:

```
{
   "firstName": "Duke",
   "lastName": "Java",
   "age": 18,
   "streetAddress": "100 Internet Dr",
   "city": "JavaTown",
   "state": "JA",
   "postalCode": "12345",
   "phoneNumbers": [
      { "Mobile": "111-111-1111" },
      { "Home": "222-222-2222" }
   ]
}
```

From, for example, pair `"firstName": "Duke"` how we can define what's type of the value? As i understood type of the name it the name-value pair is `string` always.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is JSON and why would I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects have the form:

```
{"key1": value1, "key2": value2, ...}
```

Keys must be strings. `valueX` can be any valid JSON "data type" (i.e. object, array, numbers, string, true, false, null).

http://json.org/ has a nice syntax diagram:

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/object.gif))</sub>

In your example, `{"firstName": "Duke", "lastName": "Java", ...}` is an object, `"firstName"` is a key of the object and `"Duke"` is one of the values, which is a string.