# Polymorphism for Json

Tags: arrays, json

making json polymorphism;i can make the arrays for each objects strings or integers but i couldn't hold the all strings or integers for one object. can you give me a simple example for creating a new json polymorphism.

```
public class jsonvalue {

jsoninteger []jinteger;
jsonstring []jstring;

String [] s;
int i=0;
int p=0;

  public jsonvalue()
{ 
jinteger=new jsoninteger[100];
jstring =new jsonstring[100];
s=new String[100];
} 
  public void add(String x,jsonstring a){

      s[i]=x;
      jstring[i]=a;
      i++;

  }
  public void add(String x,jsoninteger b){

      s[i]=x;
      jinteger[p]=b;
      i++;
      p++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what JSON is.

Comment: can't you give me link or something to learn what JSON is.

Comment: JSON is "JavaScript Object Notation". See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it

Comment: JSON is a data interchange format.  It's basically XML, except it uses a much more concise syntax (a syntax which is a subset of JavaScript)

Comment: Also, the above code is not Javascript, so it could confuse other people trying to help that you have labeled this post "JavaScript"

Comment: @user3028956: *"can't you give me link or something to learn what JSON is."* Sure: http://json.org