# JSON.parse SyntaxError: unable to correctly modify input (data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Here is my code,

```
function rdsxsVal() {
'use strict';
$.get("../cgi-bin/csps_rdsxs.cgi?r=" + Math.random(), function (data) {

    spsVal = JSON.parse(data);
```

I use the debugger in Opera and see, `data = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding=...`

the error is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

so I have researched a lot and tried what I can with no success.

`JSON.parse('"ssdata"');` does not fail. This is not useful other than it confirms the format I need to correct the error. I need single quotes outside the double quotes.

So I tried adding single quotes by, `data = "'" + data + "'";`
but this results in,

`data = "'<?xml version="1.0" encoding=...`

which is wrong, the single quotes are in the wrong place.

I thought maybe the `"` (double quotes) was a debugger effect so used,

```
data = "" + data;
```

but this had no effect.

I also tried replacing the `"` with `'` but this did not work,

```
data = data.toString().replace("\"", '\'');
```

I have a feeling there is a simple answer but I'm just not seeing it.

Solution:
So by using the suggestion from @chris-vdp I now have the following working code and from the debugger I can confirm it enters the .done section and not the .fail even though both sections are the same for some reason.

```
function rdspsVal() {
'use strict';
$.ajax({
    url: "../cgi-bin/csps_rdsps.cgi?r=" + Math.random(),
    dataType: "xml"
}).done(function (data) {
    spsVal = data;
    if (!rdspsInit) {
        home();
        rdspsInit = true;
    }
    rdspsVal();
    timer1();
}).fail(function (data) {
    spsVal = data;
    if (!rdspsInit) {
        home();
        rdspsInit = true;
    }
    rdspsVal();
    timer1();
});
```

}

in place of the original,

```
function rdspsVal(){
$.get("../cgi-bin/csps_rdsps.cgi?r="+Math.random(), function(data) {
 spsVal = JSON.parse(data);
}).done(function(){
    if(!rdspsInit){
     home();
     rdspsInit = true;
    }
     rdspsVal();
     timer1();
}).fail(function(){
    if(!rdspsInit){
     home();
     rdspsInit = true;
    }
    rdspsVal();
    timer1();
});
```

}

Comment: XML is not JSON, you can't parse it with the JSON object.

Comment: You should learn first [what JSON is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and it was a simple answer after all. In my defence I inherited a project including partially working js code and I have been working through bugs. This is the last one. As to why the code is written like this I still need to find out and then what it should be doing.

Comment: your fail block should be different than your done block. It is executed in the case where the server returns an error, ie a 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.get` is shorthand for `$.ajax`. What you seem to be missing is the datatype. jQuery will parse your results for you.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "../cgi-bin/csps_rdsxs.cgi?r=" + Math.random(),
  success: success,
  dataType: "xml"
});
```

EDIT: example of assigning data to the variable using Promises.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../cgi-bin/csps_rdsxs.cgi?r=" + Math.random(),
    dataType: "xml"
}).done(function(data) {
    spsVal=data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that but how to get the parsed output into my var, spsVal?