# Javascript Populate key value with value is an array

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate over a JSON in javasacript and create something like this as output

```
   {
    "seriesData": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "data": [
                5,
                3,
                4
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane",
            "data": [
                2,
                2,
                3
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Joe",
            "data": [
                3,
                4,
                4
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I essentially need to add values in data array for each key inside my for loop.

Input looks like: 
`{"Records":[{"name":"Jan'10","users":[{"name":"John","y":5},{"name":"Jane","y":2},{"name":"Joe","y":3}]},{"name":"Jan'10","users":[{"name":"John","y":3},{"name":"Jane","y":2},{"name":"Joe","y":4}]},{"name":"Jan'10","users":[{"name":"John","y":4},{"name":"Jane","y":3},{"name":"Joe","y":4}]}]}`;

Can someone please suggest how can this be achieved.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Don't you know how to add values to an array?

Comment: How to associate an array to a key in JSON ? And I need to keep track of all the arrays as I need to decide iteratively based on key which array to add new value to

Comment: I think you have to provide more information, especially how your original data looks like and how exactly you are trying to convert it.

Comment: A lost cause, I know, but: that's not JSON.

Comment: @Juhana please elaborate.

Comment: @Robbert What the OP has is an array of objects. If he passed it to a JSON serializer it would be turned into a string that would be in a JSON format. JavaScript object != JSON. (edit: although the original input does look like JSON.)

Comment: @Juhana the only difference being that the collection does not have a name? e.g. `{"collection":[{}, {}, {}]}`

Comment: @Robbert No. JSON is a data transfer format (JS Object **Notation**). If you have *an actual object* then it's not a *notation*. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/383699/502381

Comment: @Juhana right, got it. Either way, OP didn't say it was JSON.

Comment: I am not sure if that helps, I changed the input to JSON as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
var dataList = {};
function addData(name){
    if( dataList[name] == undefined)
        dataList[name] = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        dataList[name].push(arguments[i]);
    }

}
function packData(){
    var pack = []
    for(var e in dataList){
        pack.push({
            name: e, 
            data:dataList[e].sort(function(a,b){return a-b})
        });
    }
    return pack;
}

addData("Joe", 1);
addData("Jan", 2, 10);
addData("Joe", 3, 5, 10, 18, 500);
addData("Jan", 4);
addData("Joe", 5);
addData("Jan", 6);
console.log( packData() );
```

use `addData(name, data);` to append data to a name and afterwards pack this data with `packData()`

EDIT:
Sry switched to PHP for a while... fixed the script XD

Comment: dataList[name] .. what's that ? You are suggesting to use String as index ?

Comment: an JS Object `var a = {foo:"bar"}` can be accessed via `a.foo` or `a['foo']` which is usefull in manny cases.

Comment: Can you kindly suggest .. how can I sort this on keys ?

Comment: And if I want to push two values ..then

Comment: you can sort the data as follows: `dataList[e].sort(function compare(a, b) {return a-b})`

Comment: i updated the example with the sorting and the "adding mort than two values at once".