# Export javascript object to use it in another program

Tags: javascript, object, export

I'm trying to build an offline navigation.

I have two versions of my program: online and offline.

1. I create an object based on a google maps request
2. I want to "store" this object somehow
3. I want to access this object in the offline version of the program.

If I do `console.log(object)` google chrome gives me the object, but I cant just copy it and paste in the offline version.

Any ideas how to "export" the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stringify your object -> JSON.stringify( yourObject );
2. Save your file as JSON ( you can use library like : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ )
3. Upload this JSON to your offline app
4. Parse it -> JSON.parse( youJsonFile.json )

Comment: @lornz see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it?

Comment: I just need to store the object one time and then I wont have to touch the online version ever again.
So I thought about JSON.stringify too. 

I did: 
JSON.stringify(myObject) and printed it with console.log. Then I copied that string into the offline version and tried to parse it. But that gives me an error "error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token f SyntaxError: Unexpected token f
    at Object.parse (native)"

Comment: Can you paste here your stringified object ?

Answer (score 0):

I guest you use HTML5 for you task? In the case answer is yes, is ease save local data for your use in offline mode. You can read this tutorial for `localStorage` object [Local Storage in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Now, the next code help you to save online data in local storage, and access this in offline:

```
function init() {
   var googleMapObject = null;

   // This is first status verification
   if (navigator.onLine) {
      googleMapObject = anyMethodToGetData();

      // Save remote object in local storage
      localStorage['googleMapsObject'] = JSON.stringify(googleMapObject);
   } else {
      // In offline mode, return local storage data
      if (localStorage['googleMapsObject']) {
         googleMapObject = JSON.parse(localStorage['googleMapsObject']);
      }
   }

   return googleMapsObject;
}
```

The `init` method is call in `load/ready` event. If you need detect change in online/offline state, use [online/offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events).

Regards!!

Comment: I thought about that too.
But I need to transfer the offline version to another device. So the local storage of my browser won't be avaible.