# retrieving localstorage and use for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the service

```
.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {

    get: function(key, defaultValue) {
      return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
},
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }
  }
}]);
```

and I do `console.log($localstorage.getObject('name'));` it gave me an error saying `Unexpected token [`

Here's how my key and value look like as localstorage

```
{["a","b","c"]}
```

what's wrong actually?

Comment: It's probably not valid JSON

Comment: are you using double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: @wZVanG tried double quote, doesn't work too.

Comment: `name {["a","b","c"]}` is invalid JSON, why `name` is included?, correct JSON: `{["a","b","c"]}`, without any variables

Comment: The quotes doesn't really matter as long as it's still an array inside an object. You have to JSON.stringify it before storing.

Comment: Try: `console.log($window.localStorage[key])` before return, and say me what shows your console

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure your objects are properly stored with the `JSON.stringify` method. However if you are saving manually be sure to use a **[valid format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)**.

```
//Correct usage to store JSON objects

saveObject: function(key, value){
    $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
},

getObject: function(key) {
    var result = {};
    try{
        result = JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }catch(e){
        console.log("JSON invalid format", e)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm not talking bout set yet, I can't retrieve the array now.