# How to save RecyclerView content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a RecyclerView as a checklist that can be used as a grocery list for example, first the user adds the product(item), the price and the store, then my app adds this `item` object into my ArrayList adapter; each item in my adapter is a relative layout with 3 TextViews for the product, price and store. The problem occurs when the user shuts down his device or closes the app: the RecyclerView resets to nothing.

What is the easiest way to save items in a RecyclerView so that it stays? Do I save in the cache?

Comment: Save the data to persistent storage. For something small, put it into a JSON Object, store that JSON as a string in `SharedPreferences`. Then when you re-open the app, populate the `ArrayList` from the storage. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: So I save my ArrayList data in SharedPreferences?

Comment: Yes, you will need to convert into a `String` first because SharedPreferences can only store primitive types. Therefore the best way to convert to a String is to keep the data structured using JSON.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the json part

Comment: JSON is like a dictionary, it's a way to store Key-Value pairs. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/383692/3358186 for more information and some examples of what it looks like. Then search for how to use JSON and Android (for reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: @RogueBaneling Why don't you post your suggestion as an answer? (genuine question)

Comment: Thanks dude helped me a noobie like me a lot

Comment: So I can store a String array, no? It's primitive type

Comment: @KevinJohnson I didn't feel that my original comment was descriptive enough (and instead was more of a keyword list to Google).

@JamesA I have updated my answer below, it is possible to store a `Set<String>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
or
[SQLite Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to save the data to [persistent storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in some way. For something small, it would be best to use `SharedPreferences`. Then, when you re-open the app, load the data from `SharedPreferences` into your `ArrayList`, then populate the `RecyclerView`.

To use `SharedPreferences` you will need to convert your data into a `String`, because `SharedPreferences` can only handle primitive data types. The best way to convert lots of data to a `String` is by converting the data into a `JSONObject`, then that `JSONObject` into a `String` (which can be stored in `SharedPreferences`).

JSON is like a dictionary, it's a way to store Key-Value pairs. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383692/3358186) for more information and some examples of what it looks like. Then search for how to use JSON and Android (or reference the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)).

**EDIT:** If your `RecyclerView` is showing a simple amount of data, you may be able to store a `Set<String>` in your `SharedPreferences`. See [this relevant documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

Comment: How do I convert my strings into JSONObject? And how do i convert them back?