# How to extract specific info from json

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get the subdivisions.names.en from the json below but keep getting a "TypeError: location.subdivisions.names is undefined" error. I'm sure it something simple & prob just need more sleep ;)

I can get other the info I need - this works:

```
alert(location.city.names.en + ' ' + location.postal.code);
```

But this does not:

```
alert(location.subdivisions.names.en);
```

Here is my json:

```
{
    "continent": {
        "code": "OC",
        "geoname_id": xxx,
        "names": {
            "fr": "Océanie",
            "pt-BR": "Oceania",
            "zh-CN": "大洋洲",
            "es": "Oceanía",
            "de": "Ozeanien",
            "ja": "オセアニア",
            "en": "Oceania",
            "ru": "Океания"
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "longitude": xxxx,
        "latitude": -xxxx,
        "time_zone": "Australia/Melbourne"
    },
    "subdivisions": 
    [
        {
            "names": {
                "ru": "Виктория",
                "pt-BR": "Vitória",
                "en": "Victoria"
            },
            "iso_code": "VIC",
            "geoname_id": xxxx
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"subdivisions": [ ...` indicates, that this variable is an array of objects. You need to index the proper entry:

```
  alert(location.subdivisions[0].names.en);
```

Please be aware that there must not be any entry

`"subdivisions": [], ...`

and a lot of them, so there must be some logic / check on the index.

`location.subdivisions.length` might help

Answer (score 2):

"subdivisions" is defined as an array in your json file. Depending on what is intended, either change it to be just a hash (remove the square brackets) or modify the access to

```
alert(location.subdivisions[0].names.en);
```

Answer (score 0):

[You should have a look at what is JSON and how to use it properly because apparently you seem to lack the basic knowledge of how JSON is structured.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

That being said, the reason why `location.subdivisions.names.en` is undefined is because in your JSON it does not exist.

`subdivisions` is also an array of objects.

In order to access what you are trying to you must use `subdivisions[0].names.en`.

Comment: I think the question isn't clear.  It looks like location is a variable that this json is being assigned to (look at what works and what is included in location and you'll see what I mean).  I believe the actual issue is that subdivisions is an array...

Comment: I assume that `location` in the given context of the json must be addressed `location.location.~`

Comment: I'd appreaciate if whoever downvoted gave a reason since I have fixed the answer.