# how to Change the Json data into required Json

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsonp

Hey guys i am trying to change the Json data to my required Json and store it into a new Json. My Json data is

```
var dataSet = {"ContractNumber":["17102367","17054217","17835641","17597810","17131176","17592158","17601558","17457472","17843672","17555883"],
"ContractType":["CP4","USV","EAT","UNI","UPS","UPS","UPS","UPS","UPS","UPS","123"]}
```

required Json in

```
var dataSet =[
["17102367", "CP4"],
["17054217", "UNI"],
["17054666", "UN3"],
["17054217", "U23"],
["17102367","CP4"],
["17054217","USV"],
["17835641","EAT"],
["17597810","UNI"],
["17131176","UPS"],
["17592158","UPS"],
["17601558","UPS"],
["17457472","UPS"],
["17843672","UPS"],
["17555883","UPS"],
["","123"]
]
```

Comment: none of this is JSON

Comment: i checked in http://jsoneditoronline.org/ and it got passed as a json

Comment: That's great you're trying to code, you can write it in your Facebook status, but StackOverflow is for asking for help with a code, which is not working for some reason. Please don't create questions with stories what you're currently working on here, please.

Comment: @JaromandaX please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it

Comment: @Sachin - yes. and Javascript Object Notation is defined clearly as `a text format that is completely language independent` ... do you get that `dataSet` is **not a string** ... therefore it **can not be JSON**

Comment: hmm you might be right.. can you please post the same comment on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json . This contains 14050 questions on JSON. All these stupid people think same. You should enlighten them. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use array map function

```
var dataSet = {"ContractNumber":["17102367","17054217","17835641","17597810","17131176","17592158","17601558","17457472","17843672","17555883"],
"ContractType":["CP4","USV","EAT","UNI","UPS","UPS","UPS","UPS","UPS","UPS","123"]}

dataSet = dataSet.ContractType.map(function(ct, index) {
    return [dataSet.ContractNumber[index] || '', ct];
});
```

The last value will be

```
['', '123']
```

because

```
[, '123']
```

is not valid javascript

> edit: the  [, '123'] actually is valid javascript, my bad

Comment: @ jaromanda can yor please help me in this also  [{"excludeDate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"CP6","contractNumber":"17102367"},{"excludeDate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"UC1","contractNumber":"17555883"},{"excludeDate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"U04","contractNumber":"17835641"},{"excludeDate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"CP6","contractNumber":"17102367"},{"excludeDate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"UC1","contractNumber":"17555883"},{"excludeDate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"U04","contractNumber":"17835641"}]

Comment: wants to convert `var dataSet=[{"excludeDate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"CP6","contractNumber":"17102367"},{‌​"excludeDate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"UC1","contractNumber":"17555883"},{"ex‌​cludeDate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"U04","contractNumber":"17835641"},{"exclu‌​deDate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"CP6","contractNumber":"17102367"},{"excludeD‌​ate":"21/01/2016","contractType":"UC1","contractNumber":"17555883"},{"excludeDate‌​":"21/01/2016","contractType":"U04","contractNumber":"17835641"}]`

Comment: to   this format `var dataSet = [
["1710‌​2367", "CP6","21/01/2016"],
["17555‌​883", "UC1","21/01/2016"],
["178356‌​41", "U04","21/01/2016"],
.......]`