# PHP Arrays to different variables

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
Array ( [0] => { [1] => ★ Bayonet | Blue Steel (Minimal Wear) [2] => :119.41, [3] => ★ StatTrak™ Huntsman Knife | Scorched (Well-Worn) [4] => :101.65 }
```

I want these items (Comes from the API linked below) to be sorted like this: Example:

```
ItemName = "★ Bayonet | Blue Steel (Minimal Wear)";
ItemPrice = "119.41";
```

And that should be repeated for all the items. So we get a name with a price for all items listed.

Right now I have this code:

```
$priceSource = "https://api.csgofast.com/price/all";
    $priceData = file_get_contents($priceSource);
    $priceList = explode(':',$priceData);
    $priceList = explode(',',$priceData);
    $priceList = explode('"',$priceData);

    print_r($priceList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API in your code returns [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it). After you do `$priceData = file_get_contents($priceSource);` you can decode it to an array with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$decoded = json_decode($priceData, true);
```

Then you can iterate over the array and do whatever you need to do with the items and their prices:

```
foreach ($decoded as $item => $price) {
    echo "<p>$item costs $price</p>";       // for example
}
```

Comment: So what if I have an item in my inventory called ★ Bayonet | Blue Steel (Minimal Wear) and only want to get the price for that specific item. How would I do that?

Comment: If you know the exact name of the item, you can get its price by using that name as a key in the decoded array:  `$price = $decoded['★ Bayonet | Blue Steel (Minimal Wear)'];`