# How to save an array to a mysql database in laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel-5, mariadb

So i wanted to save some tags data to the database from the UI form,

**Tags:**  `["male","female","kids"]`

I tried everything like but it saves as a string, ialso tried checking if i can alter the data type to array in mysql, or json but i got this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON(255) NOT NULL' at line 1

I also tried json_encode and json_decode() but still no head so please what can i do?

Comment: Pls share what you have tried! Based on an error message only it is a bit difficult to figure out what may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any data type as JSON or Array in DB.
What you can do is use the tags field as TEXT as told by @Rick James and then  encode your input as json by using `json_encode()` method before inserting and decode it after retrieving the data from DB by using `json_decode()` method.

JSON is basically a minimal, readable format for structuring data. Which means it can be considered as a String.

Here is a good post about JSON, in case you need.
[What is JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

Comment: @MN that's very strange. It must work on server. Is there any error or exception during usage ?

Comment: Thanks. I have this error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @MN it's very hard to understand the problem from this. Though you can try printing the string before decode and after decoding, try printing the variable with var_dump()

Comment: Thanks. my problem solved with `(array) json_decode()` !!

Answer (score 0):

There is no *datatype* called `JSON`.  Instead use `TEXT` without the `(255)`.