# NODEJS: extracting strings between two DIFFERENT characters and storing them in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js, string

Using nodejs, I need to extract ALL strings between two characters that are DIFFERENT, and store them in an array for future use.
For instance, consider a file, containing a file with the following content.

```
"type":"multi",
"folders": [
    "cities/",
    "users/"
]
```

I need to extract the words: **cities** and **users**, and place them in an array. In general, I want the words between " and /"

Comment: I am extremely new to nodejs and javascript. I am using this as an exercise. I found that the way to do it is using the match method. But I am failing at placing the right delimiters

Comment: could you add your failing attempt to the question, so we have a common ground to talk

Comment: Does your file actually contain JSON? Or is that YAML? Parse it.

Answer (score 2):

As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) mentions in a comment, this looks suspiciously similar to JSON ([javascript object notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/383699/1497533).) So I'll write my answer assuming that it is. For your current example to be valid JSON, it needs to be inside object-brackets like this:

```
{
    "type": "multi",
    "folders": [
        "cities/",
        "users/"
    ]
}
```

If you parse this:

```
var parsed_json = JSON.parse( json_string );

// You could add the brackets yourself if they are missing:
var parsed_json = JSON.parse('{' + json_string + '}');
```

Then all you have to do to get to the array:

```
var arr = parsed_json.folders;
console.log(arr);
```

And to fix the annoying trailing slashes we remap the array:

```
// .map calls a function for every item in an array
// And whatever you choose to return becomes the new array
arr = arr.map(function(item){ 
  // substr returns a part of a string. Here from start (0) to end minus one (the slash).
  return item.substr( 0, item.length - 1 );

  // Another option could be to instead just replace all the slashes:
  return item.replace( '/' , '' );
}
```

Now the trailing slashes are gone:

```
console.log( arr );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
"(.+?)\/"
```

1. " preceding
2. 1 or more character (non-greedy)
3. followed by /"

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/zW2lE2/1)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. However, this extracts the " and the / with the strings. But I do not want these characters included with the substrings

Comment: What output exactly you want from that JSON?

Comment: If you Change the REGEX to (?:")(.+?)(?:\/") the ", etc. are in non-capturing Groups. If that's what you want.