# Unable to read a simple JSON

Tags: jquery

I have got a simple JSON as shown below

```
{
    "result": "success"
}
```

I am trying to read the key named result

I have tried it this way

```
var json  = {"result":"success"}
    var ajaxres = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(ajaxres.resut);
console.log(json.resut);
```

But i am getting undefined

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/187/

Comment: ajaxres.resut? should be ajaxres.result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because json variable contains an json object instead of a json string. when you change it to a string, everything works as expected.

```js
var jsonStr = '{"result": "success"}';
var ajaxres = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
console.log(ajaxres.result);

var json = {
  "result": "success"
}
console.log(json.result);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to parse a JavaScript object, not a string. You should either do:

```
var json = '{"result":"success"}';
var ajaxres = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(ajaxres.result);
```

OR

```
var json = {"result":"success"};
console.log(json.result); // json["result"] will give you the same result.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse a Javascript Object again using JSON.parse.

If you have a JSON string only then use `JSON.parse()` , like below

```
JSON.parse('{"result":"success"}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that variable `json` to hold a JSON string, you have to do

```
var json  = '{"result":"success"}'
var ajaxres = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(ajaxres.result)
```

I also fixed your typo: result instead of resut.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` converts any JSON String passed into the function, to a JSON Object.

```
var response = '{"result":"success"}'; //sample json object(string form)
JSON.parse(response); //converts passed string to JSON Object.
```

But your JSON response if already parsed. So, use `DOT(.)` to access your `key-value`

**Reference**

- [What is JSON and why would I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)
- [Parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store json as a string. Then that string should be converted to javascript object. Then It should be printed.

```
var json  = '{"result":"success"}';
var ajaxres = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
console.log(ajaxres.result);
```