# How to get JSON property without quotes?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to extract a JSON property from a JSON document. Let's simplify my example as following:

```
create table a(a text);
insert into a(a) select '{"name":"Kevin"}'::json -> 'name';
```

Now the table `a` has a value `"Kevin"` instead of `Kevin`. Do I really have to manually extract the quotes?

I am using PostgreSQL v10.1.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The JSON operator `->` returns a JSON value. That's why it's quoted. If you want a plain text, use the operator that [returns a text value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html): `->>`

```
select '{"name":"Kevin"}'::json ->> 'name';
```

Comment: That makes sense. So if some proprety `enabled` is a boolean value, I need to do `(json ->> 'enabled')::boolean`? There is no operator to automatically convert to the corresponding type? Always first to text?

Comment: JSON has no "boolean" type - in fact JSON has no data types at all. In JSON everything is a string.

Comment: I am confused by that. See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp and PostgreSQL function `json_typeof`.

Comment: w3fools is known to be full of errors. But anyway, the JSON values in Postgres are either "JSON" or text. If you want properly typed values, don't use JSON.

Comment: That's odd... what about `json_typeof(<json>)`, which returns `object, array, string, number, boolean, null`? See also http://www.json.org/value.gif on http://www.json.org/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/383699/4597030.