# What is this complex list and how do I print information from it?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

Using Python, I have a complex list that I am trying to pull various information from. When I print the entire list in question, below is what I get.

```
{'previous': None, 
 'results': [
             {'account': 'https:REDACTED', 
                  'url': 'https:REDACTED', 
               'amount': '4.32', 
         'payable_date': '2018-03-08', 
           'instrument': 'https:REDACTED', 
                 'rate': '1.4400000000', 
          'record_date': '2018-03-05', 
             'position': '3.0000', 
          'withholding': '0.00', 
                   'id': 'REDACTED', 
              'paid_at': None}, 

       {'account': 'REDACTED', 'url': 'https:REDACTED',
```

...AND SO ON... 
  }

This code -

```
for x in list:
       print(x)
```

> prints - 'previous' 'results' (which you can see are both to the left
>   side of their respective colons (:))

I want to be able to print the information on the other side of the colon (:), so:

> 'results': [{'account': 'https:REDACTED', 'url': 'https:REDACTED',...
>   etc.
>
> printing x[0] results in 'r' (first letter in 'results').

How do I get to the information on the right side of the 'results' colon (:)? Thanks

Comment: We don't have enough information to be useful to you .. You aren't giving 1) a context or 2) a programming language!

Comment: Oops, its Python. And I am sorry about the lack of information, I've never seen a list/array/whatever like this before so I don't even know what to call it!

Comment: Looks like JSON - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

Comment: That JSON clue helped, I guess JSON is very similar to a dictionary. That's what this is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a 'complex list' is, but what you're using is a python dictionary. 
The loop you need is:
`for x in list:
    print(x, list[x])`

When looping through this dictionary, 'x' is the 'key' in the dictionary (it works like the index does for a list), to get the data contained in this entry, you need to  extract it from the dictionary manually, the loop doesn't do it automatically.