# echo a rest api without including {} etc (echo in custom way)

Tags: php, rest, api

How do i echo information https://api.ubbo.no/api/player/konquer on this page without echoing the whole page with those {} etc like:

```
echo $api['username'];
```

I have read another post about this, but i could not understand anything because the link they provided there is outdated and wont work now. I have also done som research without any luck, so any help here would be higly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Why do you want to randomly output data on your page and not select the proper indices for the proper output?

Comment: If you go to that page and get the api, i want to echo the username on that api on my php page.

Comment: And why don't you do so? What the problem with echoing?

Comment: How can i do it without echoing the whole api page?

Comment: How should I know? You have not shared any of your code that handles fetching and parsing something from an API, and the link you've provided does not load anything

Comment: I have fixed the link now

Comment: But you have not shared any of your code. Looks like a JSON object to be returned from that API, and parsing that is really simple.

Comment: ...and for more info about JSON: [What is JSON and why would I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it?)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm :)