# How to access assorted decoded Json arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

I have a JSON data in the following format:

```
{
   "pr":"1",
   "0":{
      "pr":"2",
      "rfq":"2"
   },
   "1":{
      "pr":"3",
      "rfq":"3"
   }
}
```

I try to decode this JSON and when I access the first data like that:

```
$decode = json_decode( array(myjsondatas));
echo $decode->pr;
```

it prints `1`.

But when I try to access array `0` and `1` by using this syntax `$decode->[0]->pr;`, it gives me an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

How can I access the data from array `0` and `1`?

PS: This is how I did to build my json data 'myjsondatas' is not a variable

```
$arr = array("pr" => '2' ,  "rfq" => '2');
$arr1 = array("pr" => '3' ,  "rfq" => '3');

$json = json_encode(array("pr" => '1', $arr, $arr1));
```

Comment: that array is too much: `array(myjsondatas)`. make it `$decode = json_decode($myjsondatas);`

Comment: I suppose the missing `$` in front of `myjsondatas` is just a typo here..

Comment: sorry, im trying to express my json datas as a word.

Comment: after removing the array (my first comment), then the correct syntax is `echo $decoded->{'0'}->pr;`

Comment: Use `$decode = json_decode( $myjsondatas , TRUE );`

Comment: _after your edit_: so, jsondatas is not even a json but a simple array? Why json_decode it then??

Comment: forget the json_decode, simply do a `$fullarray = array("pr" => '1', $arr, $arr1);` and then `echo $fullarray[0]['pr'];`

Comment: usefull read: [What is JSON and why would I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

Comment: Anyways I did your syntax @Jeff. Everything seems working. To all of you guys thank you for your patience teaching me.

Answer (score 0):

the index is `"0"`, not `0`

You can use a variable to store the index as below :

```
$myjsondata = '{
    "pr":"1",
    "0":{
        "pr":"2",
        "rfq":"2"
    },
    "1":{
        "pr":"3",
        "rfq":"3"
    }
}';

$decode = json_decode($myjsondata);

$someIndex = "0";

var_dump($decode->$someIndex);

echo "myjsondata->0->pr gives : " . $decode->$someIndex->pr;
```

Output :

> object(stdClass)[2]
>
> public 'pr' => string '2' (length=1)
>
> public 'rfq' => string '2' (length=1)
>
> myjsondata->0->pr gives : 2