# Can JSON be added in a map.set as the key?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it is possible to add JSON as the key value for a map.set.

Adding the JSON as an object works fine:

```
var theMap = new Map();
var key = {field1 : 'value1', field2: 'value2'};
theMap.set(key, 'foo');
```

Adding the JSON during the set does not work:

```
var theMap = new Map();
theMap.set({field1 : 'value1', field2: 'value2'}, 'bar');
```

Anyone any ideas if something like this is possible?

Comment: You're not adding JSON, you're adding an object.

Comment: The second way also works, but is quite useless, as you did not keep a reference to that object.

Comment: Why does half of the programmers use the term JSON for something it is not? I don't get it. Is there some famous site out there that confuses them into this wrong use of the term?

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/383699/574531) to understand what JSON actually is.

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome Dev Console and it works both ways. Could you maybe clarify what your intent is? That way we could suggest a possible alternative easier.

Comment: Okay everyone, I apologise, it is not JSON - thanks for the education :-)

Comment: @Casey Have you tried doing a map.get? I'm basically wanting to have multiple keys, but have the flexibility of not everything being required (which is why I thought JSON/object was a good fit). I'm trying to avoid concatenating a string together for the key e.g. `theMap.set('house-married-somethingelse', 'foo');`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to set up something where a few different keys will return the same value. I can come up with a couple ways to do this, but  could you maybe give me a scenario where this would be preferred/necessary so I can think through this better?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are not using `JSON` your are using an object reference as a key. This is totally fine for a map data structure in javascript. A `map` can have anything for its **key and value** which is which is one of the reasons to sometimes pick this data structure instead of an object (which is quite similar, also key value pairs).

```
var theMap = new Map();
var key = {field1 : 'value1', field2: 'value2'};
theMap.set(key, 'foo');
```

In your second example:

```
var theMap = new Map();
theMap.set({field1 : 'value1', field2: 'value2'}, 'bar');
```

You are creating an object on the fly via an object literal. You are then using this created object literal as key for the value (the string `'bar'` in this case).

Comment: *"the object will be garbage collected"*: It would be garbage collected if it were a `WeakMap`, but in a `Map` it will not be garbage collected unless the `Map` itself is no longer referenced.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an object as a key for a `Map`, accessing that key is done via object identity. In other words you need to look it up with the *same* object, not an object with the same values.

Consider:

```js
var theMap = new Map();
let obj = {field1 : 'value1', field2: 'value2'}

theMap.set(obj, 'bar');

// you have a reference to obj
// so you can access the value with get
console.log(theMap.get(obj))

// but if you do this
theMap.set({field1 : 'value1', field2: 'value2'}, 'foo');

// you can't get foo with `obj` because having the same keys and values
// doesn't mean they are the same object:

console.log("objects are the same? ", obj === {field1 : 'value1', field2: 'value2'})

// Still setting the value in the map worked.
// You just have two distinct objects as keys 
 
console.log("keys:", ...theMap.keys())
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this. I tested out using a different object, but with the same data and you're right it did not match. I'm trying to work out how something like this can be done without having to concat a string together as the key.